# ¿Qué tipo de pregunta debería marcarse como duplicada?

Tags: discusión

Muchas veces veo que hay preguntas duplicadas con respuestas y feedback mucho mejores que en la pregunta original (por lo general la más antigua).

Puede ser que aunque se haya redactado mucho más tarde, la pregunta esté mucho mejor hecha y redactada y los usuarios puedan enlazar a ella de una manera mucho más fácil.

Por tanto, ¿de que sirve cerrar una pregunta que está teniendo mucho más éxito simplemente por el hecho de que se haya formulado más tarde que la original? ¿que tipo de pregunta debería ser la que se marcase como duplicada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traducida de [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651) de Meta Stack Exchange en ingles:

Si la nueva pregunta es mejor o tiene mejores respuestas, entonces vota para cerrar la vieja como duplicada de la nueva.

Puedes marcar y pedirle a un moderador que las junte despues del cierre si son exactamente iguales.

Si difieren por las versiones de las sistemas pertinentes, entonces no son de verdad exactamente duplicadas - asegúrate de que esto es indicado en las preguntas mismas, y proporciona enlaces cruzados para que la gente que este buscándola a una pero que encuentren a la otra tengan una ruta a la respuesta correcta.

Sí la pregunta nueva ya está cerrada como duplicada, vas a necesitar la ayuda de un moderador para hacer el cambio. Podrías marcar la original para decir que necesita la atención de un moderador, y explicar la situación ahí. El moderador puede abrir la pregunta nueva de nuevo, y después cerrar la original.

Comment: Pero si ya está marcada como duplicada ¿se puede indicar que otra diferente es duplicada de la que ya está marcada como duplicada?

Comment: Sí, por eso a veces hay cadenas de duplicadas

Comment: Corrígeme si no estoy en lo cierto pero entonces estamos ante un bucle infinito de preguntas duplicadas en bucle sin que haya ninguna original.

Comment: Sí tienes razón, entonces vas a necesitar la ayuda de un moderador. Podrías marcar la original para decir que necesita la atención de un moderador, y explicar la situación ahí. El moderador puede abrir la pregunta nueva de nuevo, y después cerrar la original.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Me has resuelto todas mis dudas. A partir de ahora haré eso. Un saludo :)

Comment: Hola @Cameron637, dejo abierta de nuevo la pregunta ya que mira el error que me ha dado cuando he intentado duplicar una pregunta de otra que está marcada como duplicada de esa.

Comment: ¿Has pedido la ayuda de un moderador?