# ¿Qué hacer cuando una pregunta está marcada cómo duplicada y es mejor que la original?

Tags: discusión

Esto viene en relación a esta otra pregunta: [¿Qué tipo de pregunta debería marcarse como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/975/qu%C3%A9-tipo-de-pregunta-deber%C3%ADa-marcarse-como-duplicada).

Esta es una aclaración de la anterior ya que en el chat, un usuario bastante activo del foro me ha comentado que el había entendido de la otra pregunta que me refería a que ambas preguntas (la que se va a marcar como duplicada y la original) estaban abiertas.

Releyendo la pregunta si que es verdad que podía llevar a confusión por lo que realizo esta y la voy a intentar redactar de una manera distinta ya que ambas preguntas, a pesar de estar relacionadas, son un poco diferentes.

En este caso yo me refiero a una pregunta, la cual se ha marcado como duplicada de otra, pero la duplicada es mejor (o al menos a mi parecer) que la original. Es decir, una pregunta que se ha formulado posteriormente tiene un mejor feedback/respuestas y un mayor número de votos que la original, por lo que puede ser que los usuarios estén más activos en la duplicada que en la original, bien porque la encuentren mejor al estar mejor redactada o porque la pregunta está mucho mejor formulada (con mayor número de palabras clave).

Reitero que en este caso hay una pregunta marcada como duplicada y otra original, en la cual la original debería ser la duplicada de la que actualmente es marcada como duplicada.

Sé que es un poco trabalenguas así que os voy a dar un caso concreto. Por ejemplo, para esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo detectar click en un ListView?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28741/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-click-en-un-listview/28750#28750)

está marcada como duplicada de esta otra:

[Click en un elemento de un listview en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10140/click-en-un-elemento-de-un-listview-en-android)

Sin embargo, la primera tiene más repuestas y, por los votos, se supone que han sido más beneficiosas para los usuarios que los de la pregunta original.

Incluso leyendo las dos preguntas más a fondo no serían duplicadas al 100% ya que, aunque el título sea parecido, el contenido por el que se pregunta es diferente.

En la primera, se solicita sobre pasar la información de usuario de una actividad a otra por medio del onclick. En cambio, en la segunda, se pregunta por la posición de un elemento de un ListView al hacer click en el.

Por tanto, tengo dos preguntas:

- ¿Se considerarían duplicadas al 100% o sólo con una parte sirve para marcar la pregunta como duplicada de otra?
- En caso de que sean realmente duplicadas **que es la pregunta principal por la que he hecho esta pregunta**, ¿deberíamos reabrir la que ya está marcada como duplicada y cerrar la original?

Si intentamos marcar como duplicada la original respecto a la que está marcada como duplicada como duplicada da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es un caso frecuente o solo es un caso aislado? ¿Cómo se define __de manera objetiva__ que una pregunta es mejor que otra? Siento que hay sesgo en la intención, porque en la pregunta que quieres reabrir hay una respuesta tuya. __*No hay reclamo ni crítica*, solo estoy señalando un hecho porque quiero entender mejor tu pregunta__. Con respecto a tus preguntas, la primera ya está respondida. Con respecto a la segunda pregunta, podrías también contestarla apoyándote en la respuesta a la pregunta duplicada, ayudarías a la creación del contenido que uno de los objetivos de los dueños.

Comment: Hola @toledano realmente entiendo tu postura y ya me imaginaba que alguien diría esto. Realmente no es algo que haya observado en esta pregunta si no en otras en Stackoverflow en inglés (aquí apenas llevo mes y medio). Puse la pregunta en la que tengo una respuesta como referencia pero podría poner muchas más (aquí no tantas porque no lleva tanto tiempo el sitio pero en Stackoverflow en inglés hay un montón con este comportamiento) y la puse simplemente porque me resulto la más sencilla de encontrar. En cuanto a mejor me refiero: mejores respuestas y más visitas, más actividad en la pregunta.

Comment: @toledano Y realmente no sé que duda tienes respecto a la segunda pregunta porque no entiendo tu duda. Sin embargo, a lo que me refiero es que si una pregunta tiene mucha más actividad que otra (la gente se mete más, y tienen muchos más puntos las repuestas, por lo que se puede deducir que a la gente le resulta de más utilidad) independientemente de si he respondido o no, creo que si esta marcada como duplicada de una que se ha formulado antes pero tiene menos "audiencia" se debería de marcar esa como duplicada y la marcada como duplicada como original. Por eso pregunté.

Comment: Una pregunta se marca como duplicada porque existe otra similar cuyas respuestas puedan ser válidas para resolver el problema, es duplicada porque es posterior en el tiempo, que una este mejor redactada o planteada que la otra no cambia eso. Además que tenga más actividad puede deberse a diferentes factores que no tengan que ver con la calidad, como que haya más usuarios con conocimiento en el tema en el momento de plantearse la pregunta, que coincida con un momento de mayor actividad general en el sitio, que el usuario que pregunta este más pendiente y conteste a los comentarios, etc.

Comment: Para mi la duplicada siempre será la segunda independientemente de cual sea mejor o tenga más votos,

Comment: @blonfu Sinceramente, no le veo mucho sentido a eso. Creo (y espero) que el fin final del sitio es ayudar a la gente con sus problemas relativos a programación. No tiene sentido que una pregunta que tenga mejores respuestas o que esté mejor redactada, lo cual puede ayudar mejor a los usuarios a enfocar su problema, se cierre por ser 'la segunda'. Pero como siempre, es una simple opinión.

Comment: Pero es que el que pregunta debería haber buscado si ya existía algo parecido y no crear una segunda pregunta. Si la pregunta no es igual y tiene matices importantes que la otra no entonces la comunidad puede reabrirla, no veo el problema

Comment: @blonfu Sinceramente, y hablo por todo el tiempo que llevo usando SOen, muchas veces he escrito una pregunta buscando las referencias anteriores y no he encontrado nada hasta que he puesto la pregunta y alguien a quien supongo le sonaría la pregunta me ha enlazado con la pregunta vieja. No dudo que haya personas que no busquen referencias anteriores pero hay muchas veces que es difícil encontrarlas o no tienes las palabras técnicas para ello.

Comment: Es posible. Supongo que otra opción sería fusionar las dos en una sola  si las respuestas son válidas para ambas, manteniendo la que este mejor redactada.

Comment: @blonfu Sí, esa opción sería la más factible y la más eficiente a mi parecer. Centralizar todas las buenas respuestas en una sola pregunta la cual esté bien redactada. Un tipo de "merge" o algo así de las preguntas duplicadas.

Answer (score 1):

Hace un mes aproximadamente se liberó una carácterística nueva:  [Tenedores de medallas doradas y moderadores diamantados pueden editar los enlaces de duplicados](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1734/65)

Lo que se podría hacer es solicitar a un miembro con medalla dorada en la etiqueta a través del chat o los medios de contacto que este indique en su perfil o bien a usar la función de reportar para que uno de los moderadores diamantados revise el caso.

Nótese que en el caso provisto en la pregunta como ejemplo incluye la [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) la cual es al momento la única etiqueta que cuenta con un miembro con una medalla dorada.

Otra alternativa es solicitar la combinación de las preguntas. Para más detalle sobre esto véase [¿Qué son las preguntas combinadas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1592/65)