# ¿Qué son las preguntas combinadas?

Tags: soporte, faq

> Adaptación de  [What are merged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/)

¿Qué son las preguntas combinadas? ¿Quién puede combinar respuestas y cuál es la política sobre esto? ¿Qué pasa a la reputación en las preguntas y respuestas de preguntas combinadas? ¿Es esto similar al cierre de preguntas? ¿Pueden los usuarios votar para combinar y separar o esto puede ser realizado únicamente por los moderadores diamantados?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 1):

> Adaptación de la [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/) a [What are merged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/)

Las preguntas pueden ser combinadas por moderadores diamantados cuando una pregunta es un duplicado exacto de otra.

Los usuarios no pueden votar para combinar preguntas pero pueden hacer un reporte para que un moderador las combine. Esto debería hacerse sólo en los casos  que las respuestas de la pregunta a fusionar tengan sentido como respuestas a la pregunta canónica.

Esto es lo que sucede con cada publicación cuando se combinan:

#### Pregunta fuente/duplicada

- Se genera un talón (el aviso agregado por el sistema), con un enlace apuntando a la pregunta destino/canónica.

  [image: Ejemplo del aviso sacado de <!-- http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/52238/127 -->]
- Queda bloqueada para edición.
- Redirige automáticamente a la pregunta canónica si no has iniciado sesión.
- El historial de revisiones muestra

  > **Publicación combinada (origen)** a es.stackoverflow.com/questions/id/titulo

#### Pregunta destino/canónica

- Se agregan respuestas, comentarios y sus votos
- Se transfieren los favoritos/estrellas de la pregunta fuente
- El historial de revisiones muestra

  > **Publicación combinada (destino)** de es.stackoverflow.com/questions/id/titulo

---

#### Dónde encontrar preguntas combinadas

[Publicaciones anotadas > bloqueadas > combinadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=merged).

Comment: ¿Qué es eso de "talón", viene del verbo "talonario"? O es como un ticket de soporte, un aviso de duplicidad, una bandera para llamar la atención, una marca de identificación. "Hacen sentido" debería cambiarse por "tienen sentido" o "son coherentes".

Comment: @toledano: De http://dle.rae.es/?w=talón "4. m. Documento o resguardo expedido separándolo de la matriz de un libro."

Comment: La definición aunque correctísima no parece tener mucho sentido en el contexto de Stackoverflow en español. Es mejor una traducción práctica que una purista.

Comment: @toledano: Sobre la segunda parte, la respuesta es un wiki de comunidad. Asi que que por favor considera participar realizando ediciones para mejorar la respuesta. Por cierto, propongo que usemos la siguietne sala de chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53106/

Comment: @toledano: ¿qué propones como traducción práctica?

Comment: Marca, identificador, aviso, bandera, anotación, registro, reporte, etc., menos talón.

Comment: @toledano Me pregunto si es una cuestión "muy localizada". Te propongo que le demos algo de tiempo para que opinen compañeros de otras latitudes. Por cierto, Mariano también [comentó](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36131494#36131494)  (en el chat) que no lo entendía

Comment: Yo te propongo que la cambies de una vez, pero la mejor decisión es la que tú tomes.

Comment: Mi decisión fue publicarlo como un [wiki de comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/65) y me apego a ella :)

Comment: El término que se utilizó hasta ahora en los textos traducidos es `aviso`. Ejemplo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/33325/revisions