# Tenedores de medallas doradas y moderadores diamantados pueden editar los enlaces de duplicados

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Les comparto que investigando en [meta.se] sobre duplicados dí con la siguiente pregunta:

[Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

Se trata de un aviso de una nueva funcionalidad para editar los enlaces de duplicados. Esta edición la pueden realizar los tenedores de medallas doradas y los moderadores diamantados.

Por el momento, sólo la [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) cuenta con un miembro con medalla dorada, así que para el resto de las etiquetas deberemos recurrir a los moderadores diamantados.

[Medallas doradas de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)

Comment: es bueno saberlo, creo que es similar a que los usuarios con una medalla dorada sobre un tag, pueden marcarlas directamente como duplicadas ect, lo que comenta quizas sea como una amplicacion de funcionalidades sobre los tenedores de esa medalla. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel efectivamente, esto permite que se modifiquen los duplicados, pero también que haya más de uno.