# Mi pregunta-respuesta ha sido marcada como duplicada... no considero que lo sea

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

He creado una pregunta-respuesta con la idea de aportar algo ...

Me esmeré bastante en trabajar la respuesta de la pregunta, tratando de que sea clara, completa y útil.

La pregunta es sobre los media queries en CSS. **Antes de formularla busqué algo parecido y no encontré**

Después de ese esfuerzo veo con decepción que alguien la marca como duplicada de forma que la pregunta podría ser cerrada :( Ya lleva 2 votos para que la cierren, con otros 3 más la cierran.

Mi respuesta da una explicación detallada sobre el uso de las media queries, muestra los principales códigos de media queries para los distintos dispositivos, explica el uso de operadores... mientras que la otra habla de los @ (arroba) en CSS, pero sin detenerse en detalles importantes que yo trato en la respuesta a mi pregunta.

La verdad que esto decepciona un poco pues creo que si la pregunta es cerrada se pierde un contenido que considero importante.

Aquí están las dos preguntas:

- Mi pregunta: [CSS: ¿Qué son los media queries, para qué sirven, cómo se agrupan y cómo implementarlos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50786/29967)
- La otra pregunta : [¿Qué significa la arroba (@) en CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17860/29967)

¿En caso de que la cierren no podría hacer nada?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tu aporte me pareció muy bueno. Gracias por contribuir.

Respecto al cierre como duplicados:

- Una pregunta es duplicada de otra **cuando tienen la misma respuesta** (la misma forma de solucionarse).
- También está explicado en [¿Qué tipo de pregunta debería marcarse como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/975/127)

  > Si difieren por las versiones de las sistemas pertinentes, entonces no
  >   son de verdad exactamente duplicadas - asegúrate de que esto es
  >   indicado en las preguntas mismas, y proporciona enlaces cruzados para
  >   que la gente que este buscándola a una pero que encuentren a la otra
  >   tengan una ruta a la respuesta correcta.
- Incluso si fuese cerrada como duplicado, **el contenido no se pierde**. La pregunta sigue quedando tal cual está con un enlace marcando el duplicado. Cerrar una pregunta como duplicada no significa que la pregunta está mal, sólo que se puede encontrar la información en otro lado. Se puede leer sobre esto en [¿Por qué algunas preguntas son marcadas como duplicadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).
- En caso de que se cierre, quienes tienen suficiente reputación pueden votar para reabrir, o incluso se puede consultar la opinión de la comunidad en meta (tal cual estás haciendo). Más información en [¿Qué hago si estoy en desacuerdo con el cierre de una pregunta? ¿Cómo la reabro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).

Mi opinión respecto a esta votación de cierre:

- **Creo que no son duplicadas**. Ambas hablan de *Reglas de @*, pero desde diferentes ángulos. De hecho, en mi respuesta a [¿Qué significa la arroba (@) en CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17860/127), obvié intencionalmente incluir información de *@media queries* por ser un tema un poco extenso como para que sea relevante en esa respuesta... Y recién la edité para agregar el enlace a tu pregunta.
- Tiene 2 votos de cierre, pero también 3 votos para dejar abierta, por lo que ya se terminó [la revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/30815).
- No te decepciones. Es lo que opinan otras personas, pero no significa que tu pregunta esté mal. Siempre habrá alguien que opine diferente. Es ser parte de una comunidad.

Comment: +1000 "Siempre habrá alguien que opine diferente. Es ser parte de una comunidad"

Comment: Me parece recordar que las preguntas duplicadas sí se borran pasado un cierto tiempo (no automáticamente) si no aportan nada nuevo. Que no sería aquí el caso si hubiese acabado como duplicada pues sí aporta algo nuevo. Aunque, al ser opinable si aporta o no algo nuevo, sí es cierto que en general una pregunta duplicada supone un cierto riesgo de que lo que en ella hay desaparezca.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no se eliminan. Podés ver el punto 7 en mi respuesta a [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/127) ... Solamente podría eliminarse por el voto de usuarios (al igual que cualquier otra pregunta)... Por otro lado, si considerás que una respuesta a una pregunta que fue marcada como duplicada aporta contenido, podrás emitir un reporte para que un moderador la migre a la otra pregunta.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista no deberia de haberse marcado como dupe, y esta bien se agregue este contenido pero deberia ser considerado Wiki de comunidad, formulada y respondida el 21 feb. a las 16:48, se hablo de esto hace tiempo.

Comment: @Jorgesys No entendí qué publicación *debería* ser wiki ni por qué.