# ¿Cuál es el criterio que han seguido para marcar esta pregunta como duplicada?

Tags: discusión, meta, motivos-de-cierre, pregunta-específica

¿Podrían explicarme los usuarios:  @Mariano, @DevJoel, @lois6b y @ArtEze cuál es el criterio que han seguido para marcar como duplicada esta pregunta?

[¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1552/29967) **formulada el 8 de marzo**

La misma es *supuestamente* duplicada de otra pregunta **formulada el 28 de abril**:

[Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/29967)

Yo intuyo de parte de algunos una cierta intención de *anular* mi presencia y mis participaciones en este sitio. No lo digo sólo por esto, sino por otras actitudes y hasta ataques a nivel personal... y preguntas cerradas *supuestamente* por contenido amplio que luego de adaptarse al formato del sitio siguen cerradas.

Agradecería pues una explicación, sin echarme en cara las *normas* del sitio que indican que una pregunta más nueva puede ser duplicada de otra más vieja, sino explicando **los motivos reales** por los que mi pregunta es duplicada de una aparecida mes y medio después.

No quiero que me expliquen las *normas*, las cuales sólo parecen servir cuando conviene.

Resulta que uno puede terminar hartándose (perdón por la expresión), de actitudes como estas y puede terminar decidiendo invertir su tiempo en algo más productivo que entrar en diatribas que suenan a problemas de adolescentes.

Comment: Por cierto, si te sientes a gusto de exponer más etiquetas en inglés, si es que aún las hay, puedes publicar en meta. y si la próxima te la cierran por duplicado, no te preocupes, está en tu conciencia que ayudar fue de tu autoría.

Comment: La próxima, ban para toledano o Cedano. Borré los comentarios porque los considero que no se tratan de esta pregunta.

Comment: @ArtEze - Estás pregunta están permitidas en Meta? Ya que se dirige a 4 usuarios en concreto... no sería mejor discutir esto en el chat?

Comment: @aldanux Es válido, habla de una pregunta que se cerró.

Answer (score 7):

Como comenté en tu pregunta original luego de la edición:

En cuanto a la nota que agregaste recién... "*no soportasen nada de lo que yo haga aquí*" -No, es justamente lo contrario, creo que no podrías estar más equivocado en cuanto al motivo del cierre.

Fui el primero en sugerirlo como duplicado y lo sostengo.

1. La fecha en la que se publicó ayuda a determinar, pero no es condicionante.
2. La pregunta sobre la cual se cerró es más completa, se generó en parte gracias a esta pregunta tuya (gran aporte), pero cubre mejor el tema, y fue editada con el resultado por un moderador.

> El punto 1 no me sirve, ya lo dije en la pregunta y el punto 2 no lo entiendo. La edición no es superflua, es lo que pienso y creo que terminaré abandonando esta comunidad.

Como lector de tus publicaciones, a las cuales suelo votar +1, sería una lástima, pero hacé lo que sientas. Espero que en algún momento puedas entender que esto no es en absoluto un tema personal, y recuerdo haber publicado fuertemente en contra de cerrar una pregunta tuya, cuando así lo creí. Cerrar una pregunta como duplicado no es atacarte, estás confundido en el concepto. Yo mismo cerré como duplicado preguntas mías (sin ser masoquista, al menos no en ese caso).

El punto 1 responde directamente a la cuestión de las fechas planteado en tu pregunta. La forma en que relacionás un cierre con "un ataque personal" jamás lo voy a entender, y mucho menos compartir. Se cierra porque hablan sobre lo mismo. ¿Acaso no tratan el mismo tema? Yo estoy convencido de que sí. Y ese cierre apunta a organizar mejor el contenido del sitio.

En cuanto al punto 2, la pregunta sobre la cual se cerró:

- incluye a todas las etiquetas de tu publicación.
- agrega más etiquetas a traducir.
- agrega el motivo por el cual existen esas etiquetas en inglés.
- le da una visión completa al tema.
- ofrece una propuesta global al problema.
- sugiere etiquetas a utilizar para todas (fue un wiki de comunidad sobre el cual se trabajó en conjunto).
- es una propuesta en concreto, que se dirigía a un moderador, para que se solucione.
- fue editada por un moderador, quien siguió esa propuesta para realizar el cambio.
- se dejó registro de que el cambio fue realizado y entró en vigencia.

Estos son los motivos por los cuales pienso que es más completa y trata mejor el tema. Si yo estuviese buscando en Meta una pregunta sobre esas etiquetas en inglés, preferiría ver esa publicación. Ese es el motivo del cierre. Para organizar Meta, algo en lo que participo frecuentemente.

Tu edición creo que es superflua y la revertiría. Porque no aclara nada de la pregunta en sí. Ese mensaje no aporta contenido sobre las etiquetas, sino sobre una queja, que tiene lugar en este hilo, no en esa pregunta.

Respecto a tu publicación, creo que fue un gran aporte porque trajo a mesa de discusión algo importante para el sitio. La voté +1 y me pareció excelente que se publique. El tema luego fue cerrado en otro lado. La pregunta sobre la cual fue cerrada ([Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/127)) te da crédito sobre el planteo original del tema. Realmente, considero que fue excelente que hayas sido el primero en plantearlo en Meta. No estoy llamándola *simplista*, ni estoy atacándote, ni nada semejante. Creo que ese tema en Meta queda mejor organizado así.

Comment: El punto 1 no me sirve, ya lo dije en la pregunta y el punto 2 no lo entiendo.  La edición no es superflua, es lo que pienso y creo que terminaré abandonando esta comunidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano agregué más información en mi respuesta intentando responder. No dudes en comentarme si me faltó algo.

Comment: Tu respuesta da la impresión de que sólo tienen derecho a preguntar gente que se dedique a tiempo completo a esto y que formula preguntas perfectas que lo abarquen todo... las otras preguntas _simplistas_ terminarán siendo cerradas, como la mía en este caso. Mientras que del otro lado, en SO, me cierran preguntas como _demasiado amplias_... y siempre el mismo discurso: _excelente trabajo..._ pero te lo cerramos. O algo falla o estoy llegando a la conclusión de que en SO no hay sitio para todo el mundo, sino para un pequeño clan.

Comment: @A.Cedano Cerrar una pregunta como duplicada no es bajo ningún aspecto en absoluto decir que no tenés derecho a algo. De nuevo, tengo la impresión que estás equivocado sobre lo que implica un cierre. Es lo que te respondí en [Mi pregunta-respuesta ha sido marcada como duplicada… no considero que lo sea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1440/127)... Sobre el resto de las preguntas cerradas en SO, prefiero no opinar sin saber.

Comment: Creo que terminaré escribiendo en un blog, quizá le llamaré ***stackoverflow delusions***, porque para serte sincero, no quiero perder más mi tiempo en este abrir y cerrar preguntas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bien, cuando lo hagas, me gustaría leerlo, y podés encontrarme en el chat para pasarme el enlace (es en serio, no quiero sonar como que lo estoy menospreciando, que no se interprete como tal).

Answer (score 6):

No suelo publicar mucho pero como la pregunta está dirigida hacía mi explícitamente lo haré con el fin de aclarar los puntos que expone.

En primer lugar no siento formar parte de "algunos" y tampoco intenté "anular" a ningún usuario ni antes, ni ahora ni después tenga la reputación que tenga *(usuarios nuevos o con más tiempo aquí)* , jamás ataqué a nadie y mucho menos tengo algo contra usted. Por lo tanto estoy en desacuerdo con su postura de considerar las decisiones de la comunidad como algo personal cuando no lo son.

Tomando en referencia el cierre de la pregunta en particular, la consideré como duplicada porque la otra pregunta ofrece una propuesta más globalizada del tema,  Es decir la mayoría de etiquetas de su pregunta están ahí además preguntas de meta relacionadas a otras sugerencias para etiquetas especificas *(que también están dentro de las etiquetas que usted plantea)* .

Igual me parece que este tema  *(cierres)*  son *punto de vista , opiniones, forma de ver las preguntas* que se toman en cuenta para actuar, por lo cuál puede generar descontentos como en este caso y quizá se vea como decisiones equivocadas pero como dije son puntos de vista que se respetan siempre aunque no se esté de acuerdo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Se pudo haber buscando el _consenso_  ¿no?, para mejorar la pregunta original, la más antigua, si es que necesitaba ser mejorada o ampliada, en lugar de crear una que la _sobrevolase_, cerrando luego la otra. Como imaginarás, hubo un trabajo para elaborar la pregunta y se podía seguir construyendo sobre ese trabajo ya hecho. Incluso la pregunta-respuesta que sobrevolaba la primera podía existir perfectamente como respuesta de la pregunta que se planteó primero. Considero que no han sido tan coherentes como piensan en este asunto.

Comment: Con el primer punto pudo haberse realizado, lo segundo es que se reconoce el trabajo que se empleó en dicha pregunta de eso no hay duda alguna. Y sobre el ultimo punto tienes derecho a considerar un punto de vista diferente es justamente a lo que se está expuesto al realizar dichas acciones, no siempre se está de acuerdo haciendo que se vean como decisiones equivocadas. Saludos y a seguir contribuyendo :)

Answer (score 5):

Estimado A. Cedano.

Me pregunto si estás consciente que estás entre los 28 usuarios que tienen +5 000 de reputación en este sitio. Los puntos de reputación que has ganado son muestra de que esta que comunidad aprecia tus contribuciones.

Me parece muy bien que hayas traído tu inconformidad a este espacio, para eso está. Afortunadamente Mariano, quien está entre los ocho miembros con +10 000 puntos de reputación y uno de los miembros de la comunidad con más talento para responder este tipo de publicaciones, ha sido el primero en responder.

Eres muy apasionado. Se ve en el número de tus publicaciones y en tus intentos por encontrar formas de contribuir con contenido de calidad.

A mí me gustaría que continúes participando pero también que cuides las formas. Recuerda que el sitio tiene una política de [comportarse bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) la cual en mi opinión es uno de los pilares fundamentales para que esta comunidad funcione. En mi opinión la comunidad es muy tolerante en este sentido, lo sé porque yo también he tenido "situaciones" con algunos miembros de la comunidad. En alguna ocasión la falta fue mía se me llamó la atención. Al darme cuenta de mi falta la reconocí y pedí perdón, y todo bien, aquí sigo con la intención continuar. En otras simplemente decidí en lugar de confrontar enfocarme en continuar participando, esto porque no había beneficio alguno en llevar esa confrontación.

En la "situación" de la cual asumo la culpa, Juan M ofreció mediar. No estoy juzgando, sólo lo menciono para que tanto tú como quien lea esto tenga presente que está disponible ese recurso.

Ya por último, humildemente me voy a atrever a hacerte una petición, por favor evita amedrentar y usar calificativos contra otros miembros. Eso no es comportarse bien.

Comment: [Respuesta de Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/820/65) a otro hilo sobre inconformidades.

Answer (score 2):

Una de las cosas que me seducen más de la red Stack Exchange es la transparencia. En casi todos los casos uno puede saber quién ha hecho qué: marcar para cerrar, reabrir, revisar, comentar... todo. Además, Meta nos ofrece un espacio para comentar esos actos, intentando llegar a consensos (sí, consensos, o al menos a mayorías de opinión) para hacer la comunidad mejor.
En un ámbito como el nuestro, el informático, esto es una herramienta utilísima porque nos ayuda a centrar el debate y valernos de hechos objetivos.

Sin embargo, hay casos en los que por algún motivo esa objetividad en la evaluación de los hechos se va al garete.

Reproduzcamos los hechos:

- Preguntas, utilizando la etiqueta [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) [¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1552/83) curiosamente te contesto yo indicando que esa lista está predefinida y sugiriendo que se traduzcan.
- Hay un debate en los comentarios, [vamos revisando la lista](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1553/revisions) y poco a poco crece bastante el tema.
- Cuando veo que probablemente la visibilidad de la respuesta es baja (no olvidemos que se preguntaba *Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés*) decido relanzar el tema, utilizando la etiqueta [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva), [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/83) para explicitar que es algo que desearíamos cambiado.
- ArtEze se pule la lista de un plumazo y [¡zas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1888/9) Ya tenemos la lista de etiquetas en español. ¡Fantástico trabajo!
- Pasado un tiempo, alguien optó por marcar tu pregunta de discusión o soporte como duplicada de la mía de solicitud de acción por parte de los moderadores. Discrepo de la idea pues las respuestas no son intercambiables, pero al ser temas relacionados no creo que tampoco sea algo tan descabellado. Sea como fuere, la esencia es la misma: gracias a tu aviso inicial, la comunidad se movió, llegó a un consenso y pasó a traducir algo. ¿A qué viene montar todo el pollo en relación a si una se marcó como duplicada de otra?

[Hace unos días](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2301/83) definí como de *llanero solitario* la actitud de trabajar uno solo en soluciones que afectan a la comunidad. Por suerte o por desgracia, este sitio da poder a los usuarios para que estos estiren cada uno de su parte esperando llegar a puntos de entendimiento.

Hay veces en que planteas dudas interesantes pero luego se ve que no son discusiones, sino [quejas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2279/qu%C3%A9-ocurre-con-la-pregunta-manejar-conexiones-a-bases-de-datos-mysql-mediante/2301#comment7266_2279):

> @ArtEze Ninguna respuesta me ha servido en sí. Este caso me ha servido en general para sacar mis propios conclusiones sobre el espíritu que impera en dos o tres usuarios de esta comunidad, quienes al parecer marcan las pautas de la misma. El problema no era la pregunta en sí, la prueba es que la misma ha sido modificada cumpliendo las supuestas normas de SO, sin embargo permanece cerrada. He sacado mis propias conclusiones, las cuales quizá exponga en algún momento, si lo considero útil.

¿Has perseguido el tema? ¿Has comentado en las respuestas? Hablas de que *ha sido modificada cumpliendo las supuestas normas de SO, sin embargo permanece cerrada*. Pero, ¿acaso es automática la reapertura? Actualiza tu pregunta, indica que hiciste modificaciones y seguro que la comunidad se planteará si ha lugar reabrirla (para mí, sí, si bien sigo pensando que es mejor trocear la respuesta).

[Dices](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2377/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-criterio-que-han-seguido-para-marcar-esta-pregunta-como-duplicada/2383#comment7394_2383):

> Gracias por tu respuesta. Se pudo haber buscando el consenso ¿no?, para mejorar la pregunta original, la más antigua, si es que necesitaba ser mejorada o ampliada, en lugar de crear una que la sobrevolase, cerrando luego la otra. Como imaginarás, hubo un trabajo para elaborar la pregunta y se podía seguir construyendo sobre ese trabajo ya hecho. Incluso la pregunta-respuesta que sobrevolaba la primera podía existir perfectamente como respuesta de la pregunta que se planteó primero. Considero que no han sido tan coherentes como piensan en este asunto.

Y [en otro lugar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2377/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-criterio-que-han-seguido-para-marcar-esta-pregunta-como-duplicada/2379#comment7391_2379):

> Me resulta curioso que se apele al consenso sólo en los casos en que uno se ve afectado personalmente. Y me pregunto, ¿por qué no se buscó el consenso para mejorar la pregunta original en lo que tuviere de mejorable, en vez de crear otra pregunta que la sobrevolase. El consenso es buenísimo, pero apliquémoslo en todo, no sólo cuando nos conviene. Creo que tampoco tú, @Mariano, has estado en este caso todo lo coherente que pretendes ser.

¿Estamos mezclando churras con merinas? ¿Acaso somos culpables de haber perseguido el tema? Aceptaste mi pregunta seis días después de que te contestara ([fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1553/timeline)) por lo que dudo que te preocupara en exceso.

Como expliqué más arriba, consideré que lo mejor era ordenar los temas y solicitar el cambio en lugar y forma para no seguir aumentando la lista añadida a una pregunta de *por qué está todo en inglés*.

Como decía antes, Stack Exchange nos ofrece la gran oportunidad de hablar de hechos objetivos. Por ello, comentarios de este tipo no solo no son constructivos sino que contribuyen a generar un monstruo innecesariamente:

[Indicas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2377/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-criterio-que-han-seguido-para-marcar-esta-pregunta-como-duplicada/2379#comment7429_2379):

> @Lamak No es un cierre, sino varios. Y también otras cosas que no vienen ahora al caso.

¿Qué es esto de sacar temas pero no sacarlos?

La verdad es que me apena que tengamos que estar debatiendo de todo esto. Siento que en Stack Overflow en español la transparencia aún necesita más entrenamiento y espero que la elección de moderadores ayude a ello. Un solo moderador (Luiggi) ha tenido que gestionar casi toda la carga de la fase Beta y entiendo que no le ha sido materialmente posible explicarse más o no ha sido su prioridad. La elección de ArtEze y freddy como otros moderadores ha aumentado la interacción de estos con la comunidad y veo con esperanza las mejoras. Mientras tanto, vamos abriendo el paso poco a poco y espero que, entre todos, contribuyamos a tener debates más constructivos.

Comment: Lo que tú interpretas como _llanero solitario_ yo lo planteo de otro modo: no soy una persona cuya actividad principal sea la informática, así que hago contribuciones puntuales, cuando puedo y aunque lo interpretes como una queja poco constructiva he visto más de una vez como dichas contribuciones son cerradas, marcadas como duplicadas, demasiado amplias, etc. Como comprenderás , tener que pasar tiempo tratando de justificar el por qué ese contenido debe quedar abierto se me hace cuesta arriba. En lo personal considero que muchos aprietan el botón cerrar muy a la ligera.

Comment: Y también considero que algunos actúan de forma algo parcial, incluso usuarios _diamantados_. Quizá han trabajado mucho en SO, eso tiene su mérito, pero quizá actúan en ocasiones de forma arbitraria , como si SO fuese algo de su propiedad. Quizá todo esto me esté llevando a la conclusión de que SO no es el lugar idóneo para colaborar como yo quiero , pues se ha convertido en un sitio en el cual no solo colaboras sino que debes defender tu contenido ante jueces no del todo imparciales.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu comentario. Entiendo tu punto y que te enoje recibir votos negativos con frecuencia en tus muy buenas respuestas. Muchas veces se nos olvida [Votar por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83) y no le hacemos bien a nadie. Dicho lo cual, debatamos tema a tema, desenredemos este nudo poco a poco en lugar de definirlo todo como bueno o malo. Si no compartes alguna decisión, habla de ella; si hay otra, habla de esa otra. Por mi parte, creo que una mayor dosis de empatía y flexibilidad ayudaría a "desenconar" el ambiente.

Comment: Las demás cosas no las he mencionado porque no vienen al caso. Pero ha habido ofensas a nivel personal que considero graves. Así como votos en contra de forma sistemática en preguntas y respuestas mías que tienen una amplia aceptación por parte de la comunidad. No considero que SO sea tan transparente como dices...

Comment: @A.Cedano haz una cosa: cuando haya ofensas a nivel personal, ¡repórtalas! No tienes porqué permitir tales actuaciones contra ti (ni realizarlas tú tampoco, claro está). Si tras reportarlas no pasa nada, ¡denúncialo en Meta! No es que me invente la solución, es que la uso todo el rato: en [es.so] he reportado más de 100 comentarios, en [so] más de 500. Nadie tiene porqué soportar los malos humores de otros y para eso están la comunidad y los moderadores, para quitarlos de en medio.

Comment: Lo he dicho más de una vez, y algunos se molestan: **el contenido de programación que existe en castellano es mediocre**, conozco un solo sitio a la altura de muchos sitios en inglés (hermosaprogramacion.com) a cuyo autor he felicitado. Mi experiencia en SO , red que al principio vi como una posibilidad para compartir contenido de calidad , me ha ayudado a entender en parte por qué hay tal carencia en la programación en castellano. Lo digo sin ánimo de ofender a nadie, más bien como una crítica para animar a crear contenido bueno y útil.

Comment: @A.Cedano ese es un debate que daría para muchos libros. Probablemente la comunidad en castellano ha recurrido demasiadas veces al inglés y ha dejado su idioma de lado. Yo mismo casi siempre busco la información en inglés pues tengo la sensación de que la castellana suele ser una traducción, si la hay. Pero de todos modos, antes de que saliera [so] el estado del contenido de programación en inglés (en modo ayuda, no documentación) era bastante pobre también. Creo que [es.so] es una oportunidad para ponernos al día. ¿Qué elementos ves tú que expliquen esa carencia?

Comment: Tienes razón en parte, yo mismo acudo casi siempre al inglés, porque no me fío del contenido en castellano y ahora menos, que he tenido la oportunidad de _tratar_ con programadores de habla hispana aquí en SO. Yo dije en alguna parte algo que molestó a algunos: considero que los programadores del idioma de Cervantes son algo _perezosos_. El sitio que comenté más arriba demuestra que es posible crear buen contenido en castellano, pero creo que estamos a años luz de eso debido a esa _pereza_. Por otra parte, la visión que algunos tienen de SO no ayudará mucho a que dicho contenido exista.

Comment: @A.Cedano y dale con las generalidades. Reitero la sugerencia de organizarse y luchar. SO se ha demostrado una gran fuente de información y SOes puede llegar a serlo. Presume buena fe, la gente al fin y al cabo quiere que el sitio crezca bien y sano, es el hijo de todos :D

Comment: A lo mejor uno de los problemas que existe con respecto a tu persona @A.Cedano son comentarios como el anterior. Creo que menospreciar como haces habitualmente a programadores de habla hispana hace que tus opiniones, aunque sean interesantes en ocasiones, no se tomen en serio. En cuanto a la vision que la gente tiene de SO, el que no coincida con la tuya no significa que sea mala ni buena.

Comment: @Pikoh Sinceramente no pretendo ser ofensivo con esto, sino animar a crear contenido bueno. No pretendo tener la verdad absoluta, sino más bien provocar alguna reacción. Yo me retracto del calificativo _perezoso_ si me muestras al menos 5 sitios en castellano con contenido de calidad, sin importar el lenguaje de programación. Por ejemplo, una de las preguntas que fue cerrada era tomada del [único autor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4220/pdo) que tiene medalla de oro en la etiqueta PDO de SO en inglés. Yo estoy de acuerdo con [la visión](https://phpdelusions.net) que él tiene de SO.

Comment: Me parece muy loable que trates de animar a crear contenido de calidad! En eso podemos estar todos de acuerdo, aunque creo que a veces te pierden un poco las formas (es una opinión personal).No puedo darte 5 sitios en castellano porque yo siempre he acudido a fuentes en ingles (aunque si recuerdo por ejemplo [LaWebDelProgramador](www.lawebdelprogramador.com) No quiero extenderme, pero si tu estás de acuerdo con la vision de SO que me has enseñado, lo que buscas no es SO sino un blog como el que enlazas...

Comment: Por cierto, me ENCANTARÍA de verdad leer cual es tu visión de SOes, que se podría hacer para mejorarlo, etc... mas alla de si una pregunta se cierra por duplicado o por demasiado amplia. Tal vez un post de meta explicando como piensas tu que conseguiríamos un sitio de mucha mas calidad nos fuera extremadamente util. Yo te animaría a hacerlo de verdad :)

Answer (score 0):

Me llegó como reporte, vi la otra respuesta, y me pareció mejor que la respuesta de tu pregunta, la marqué como duplicada. Ese fue mi motivo, les guste o no, la puse duplicada porque la otra respuesta era mejor. Pienso que quizás cometí un error en ese caso.

Me gustaría fusionar las preguntas.

<s>He marcado como duplicada la pregunta de @fedorqui y reabierto tu pregunta.</s>

Comment: Creo que fusionarlas traería más confusión al tema, ya que la respuesta a una estaría descontextualizada si estuviese en la pregunta de la otra.

Comment: @Mariano ok, entiendo, no se tratan exactamente de lo mismo.

Comment: En ese caso lo mejor sería borrar la pregunta original, dejando aquella que la ha _sobrevolado_, la de @Mariano y, si se puede, darle también los puntos que tiene la pregunta del 8 de marzo. El aviso que aparece tampoco tiene sentido: _Esta pregunta ya se hizo y tiene una respuesta. Si esas respuestas no contestan a tu pregunta con exactitud, edita la pregunta para explicar cuál es la diferencia o formula una nueva pregunta._ O sea, su pregunta del **8 de marzo ya se hizo el 28 de abril**.

Comment: @A.Cedano No la voy a borrar. Pero hago una excepción a esto, ya marqué como duplicada la otra y la tuya la dejé abierta, contradiciendo la decisión de Mariano.

Comment: ArtEze: creo que la gestión de abertura y clausura de preguntas se te está yendo un poco de las manos. Sugiero que consensuéis la gestión con el resto de moderadores o que lo dejéis en manos de la comunidad. No creo demasiado útil intentar enmendar una decisión de la comunidad de forma personal y sin consenso. Siempre es útil lo de _El moderador ♦ ideal hace lo menos posible. Pero esas pequeñas acciones pueden ser poderosas y altamente concentradas. Limitando de manera juiciosa el uso de los poderes del moderador ♦ para podar selectivamente y guiar a la comunidad_.

Comment: No sólo estás contradiciendo mi opinión, sino también la tuya (por lo que habías publicado) y la de todos aquellos que hasta ahora habían votado. Esto creo que es justamente lo contrario a lo que debería hacer un moderador.

Comment: Disculpen, ya la dejé como antes. Si quieren volver a dejarla abierta, que la abran naturalmente, y yo no intervengo.

Comment: No tengo especial interés en que se deje abierta o cerrada o duplicada (yo personalmente las dejaría abiertas, no una duplicada de la otra), pero me confundió ese baile de cierres. Enmendarte te honra. Gracias, @ArtEze

Comment: Me resulta curioso que se apele al _consenso_ sólo en los casos en que uno se ve afectado personalmente. Y me pregunto, **¿por qué no se buscó el consenso para mejorar la pregunta original en lo que tuviere de mejorable, en vez de crear otra pregunta que la _sobrevolase_**. El _consenso_ es buenísimo, pero apliquémoslo en todo, no sólo cuando nos conviene. Creo que tampoco tú, @Mariano, has estado en este caso todo lo coherente que pretendes ser.

Comment: @A.Cedano No veo el real problema. La idea de las publicaciones en meta es mejorar el sitio y comunidad. Si yo publicara una pregunta en meta, y luego hicieran una más amplia, encontraría lógico (y, es más, votaría si pudiera) que se cerrara la mía. Sobre el consenso, para están los votos de cierre, para que haya más de un usuario que piensa lo mismo. Me cuesta ponerme en el lugar de pensar que un cierre de una pregunta en meta es un ataque personal

Comment: @Lamak No es un cierre, sino **varios**. Y también otras cosas que no vienen ahora al caso.