# Problema con pregunta marcada como duplicada

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre, duplicadas

Tengo unas diferencias de opinión con la moderación realizada a unas preguntas escritas por el mismo usuario y respondidas por mí.

1. [¿Cómo transformar función tipo GroupBy de Javascript a C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/581298/301324)
2. [¿Cómo puedo realizar una comparación para determinar si un parámetro es una función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/581310/301324)

Donde la segunda pregunta se marcó como un duplicado de la primera.

1.- A mí me parecen preguntas distintas, si bien están relacionadas, pero tienen un enfoque totalmente distinto. Tanto así que las respuestas son distintas. Por lo que pienso que el cerrado por duplicada es incorrecto

2.- Hubo un enredo en los acontecimientos. En la primera pregunta @gbianchi le pide que sea más enfocada, y el usuario en vez de editar la misma pregunta creó otra nueva, pero esto no es incorrecto ya que el usuario cambió la pregunta totalmente.

Entonces le cierran la primera pregunta, y al tiempo le cierran la segunda por ser duplicado de la primera que ya estaba cerrada. Y un mismo usuario votó por el cierre de ambas **¿Para que la marca como duplicada de una pregunta que el mismo cerró?**

Finalmente el usuario se quedó con sus 2 preguntas cerradas.

Deben entender que:

- Al haber tenido respuesta el usuario ya no puede borrar las preguntas
- Y tampoco puede editarlas cambiando el enfoque

Entonces de aquí en más, cada vez que vea una pregunta similar la marcamos como duplicada de estas otras que están cerradas y no pueden recibir más respuestas??? qué sentido tiene eso?

3.- La primera pregunta que fue cerrada tampoco me parecen sus motivos, el usuario no pedía transformar una aplicación completa desde javascript a C#, pedía una función bastante pequeña. Donde el problema estaba en pasar de un lenguaje que acepta cualquier cosa como argumento en sus funciones a otro fuertemente tipado, donde el fondo del asunto era ese. No pedía el algoritmo de agrupación que ya lo tenía claro, ni que le hicieran la terea, aportó un código 100% funcional, y por si fuera poco puso ejemplos de entrada y de salida. **¿Qué más se puede pedir?**

---

**UPDATE**

Explicaré mis motivos para pensar que son distintas:

El usuario tenía esta función

```
function groupBy(collection, it) {
      let obj = {};
      for(let ele of collection){
        let index = typeof it === 'function' ? it(ele) : ele[it];
        if(obj[index ] === undefined){
          obj[index ] = [];
        }
        obj[index].push(ele);
      }
      return obj;
 }
```

Con poco esfuerzo podría haber llegado a esta otra:

```
Dictionary<object, List<object>> groupBy(List<object> collection, object it)
{
    Dictionary<object, List<object>> obj = new();
    foreach(var ele in collection){
      // object index  = ?????(1)  ?  ??(2) : ???(3); //<=== Esto falta
      if (index == null){
          // obj.Add(index , new());
      }
      //obj[index].Add(ele);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

La transformación es inmediata si ocupa `object`, y quedan muy parecidas. Si hubiera colocado algo como eso estoy seguro que no hubiera sido cerrada.

Pero como no estaba ese código, lo moderan señalándole que:

> *es que.. no estas preguntando.. estas pidiendo que lo hagan por vos ;*

Entonces el decide acotar su pregunta, y preguntar específicamente por el trozo que le falta, lo que está marcado con `?????`, que vendría a ser un `if` (por esto sospecho que él había llegado a un código parecido):

```
if (typeof x === 'function')
```

De seguir ese camino, seguro habría se habría encontrado con otros problemas, y podría haberse transformado en el caso típico de una cadena de preguntas específicas, que no resuelven de manera correcta el problema de fondo, porque el usuario arrastra código inútil a causa de una presunción inicial

No obstante, esa segunda pregunta es 100% valida en sí misma, su único problema es que la han marcado como duplicado de la primera, es decir si esta última no existiera, no habría sido cerrada

De todos modos, a mí me parece una pregunta poco interesante. No así la primera pregunta.

No sé si a alguien más le ha pasado, pero yo he visto algunas preguntas que las miro y digo "es media tonta la pregunta", y luego alguien responde con tremenda catedra y te das cuenta que esa pregunta inocente tenía un fondo importante que quizás el mismo usuario desconocía.

La primera pregunta al carecer del código, me libra de ruido innecesario, me permite a mi como usuario que respondió (y que seguramente tengo más conocimientos que el OP), en centrarme en lo que encuentro más interesante, más útil para futuros usuarios y en lo que realmente resolverá su problema. Porque para mí el problema no está en el condicional que falta, está en los tipos de datos que deben reemplazar a `object`, en el uso de "genéricos" y "delegados"

Cuando en C# se entienden estos conceptos se abre el tercer ojo, entiendes como poder crear componentes genéricos y reutilizable, otra forma de programación.

Por lo que entonces

1. La primera pregunta es un problema de tipo de datos
2. La segunda pregunta es un problema de equivalencia de un condicional

Por eso son distintas, y son tan distintas que la respuesta de la primera no sirve para la segunda y viceversa.

**Recordemos que el sitio es de preguntas y respuestas, no de resolución de problemas. Por lo que a un usuario se le permite generar más de una pregunta (siempre que sean distintas) que apunten a resolver el mismo problema, es más, incluso he visto que se alienta a esto**

---

**UPDATE 2**

Lo discutimos en el Chat, mayoritariamente y por lejos, se ha establecido que ambos cierres son correctos.

@gbianchi me aconsejó que no perdiera más tiempo una pregunta que el OP había abandonado.

Para mí era justamente el punto en cuestión, un usuario nuevo realiza 2 preguntas y son cerradas en cosas de horas ¿Qué tantas ganas tendrá de seguir participando?

Si a mí no me molesta responderle, que tanto le importa al resto "¿Qué has intentado?"

Pero por sobre todo, **¿por qué no le dejaron al menos una de las preguntas abiertas?** Es que no tiene sentido marcar como duplicada una pregunta con otra cerrada, podrían haber asumido que la primera es duplicado de la segunda, y bueno, ya está cerrada.

Entiendo que los cierres no son definitivos, pero cuando se es usuario nuevo no se entiende de esa manera.

Será la última vez que me refiera al tema, ni ha 50 preguntas juntas le he dedicado tanto tiempo.

Agradezco el tiempo a todos los que se molestaron en discutir el tema conmigo.

Comment: No puedo juzgar si realmente es duplicada o no. Pero entiendo tu frustración. Pareciera que algunos usuarios no piensan dos veces antes de "moderar" el sitio. Incluso aquí, en meta, recibí un voto por duplicada. Bueno, quien propuso esto me dejó un comentario, hice ediciones aclarando la diferencia, y lo entendió. Pero dias después, otro más la vota por duplicada. Como si no hubiera leido mi explicación. Y no se molestó en explicarme por que consideraba mi explicación no valida.

Comment: Igual, por lo que hablé con otros usuarios, pareciera que la comunidad toma malas decisiones, como permitir preguntas que no encajan con lo que supuestamente son las normas del sitio, o cerrar las que supuestamente las cumplen. Si descubro más, estaré a nada de declarar la guerra a la comunidad y dejar mi granito de arena en una correcta moderación.

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias por tu apoyo!, Porque dices que no puedes juzgar si es duplicada o no?? que antecedente te falta?

Comment: De nada! No conozco el lenguaje de programación.

Comment: @DanteS. Para que te des cuenta, 2 de los usuarios que votaron por duplicada han realizado 1 respuesta cada uno en C#, me da la impresión que ellos tampoco deben conocerlo mucho

Comment: son la misma pregunta.. básicamente en sus comentarios puso lo que necesitaba. le bastaba con editar la primera pregunta, ya que la segunda es lo mismo, y las respuestas son lo mismo. Es mas.. en su pregunta, pone que tiene claro como hacerlo, pero no puso lo que hizo. Yo cuando leo esas cosas, me suena a que no intento mucho... y ojo, que si hubiera puesto algo, cualquier cosa, con gusto la contestaba.. fijate que uno de mis comentarios es lo que explayaste en tu respuesta.

Comment: Es mas, se lo aclare en comentarios... si no edita su pregunta, parece que esta pidiendo que lo hagan por el, y no tenemos punto de avance para saber que sabe o que no. Tu explicacion es muy buena, pero si no sabe que es un lambda, o un generico, requiere una explicacion mas profunda.

Comment: Y ojo, no habia problema en que re editara la primer pregunta, si basicamente agregaba esa pregunta a su pregunta, la enfocaba y valia. Esto son los lios que a veces tienen los usuarios por apurados...

Comment: @gbianchi Te comento como vi el asunto: Yo justo estaba haciendo una función en JS para agrupar y vi estas 2 preguntas, las leí a la rápida y dije ¿cuál respondo? Decidí por la primera, por ser más antigua y estaba más completa (tiene ejemplo del resultado esperado), la respondo y la cierran. Dije, bueno borro la pregunta y la pongo en la que está abierta, pero cuando leo bien la otra pregunta me doy cuenta que no era lo mismo, mi respuesta anterior no sirve para la segunda pregunta es que ni siquiera había usado la `comparación` que el usuario solicitaba, como pueden ...

Comment: ...ser duplicadas y que no sirva la misma respuesta??? Yo creo que es parecido a este caso: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1440/301324 Donde una pregunta más amplia contiene una más específica. Pero acá hay más diferencia, porque en este caso el usuario cree que la primera se resuelve con un `if` y no es así.

Comment: Hola, si bien la pregunta no es un duplicado exacto, es una edición de la pregunta original, ahora nadie le dijo "edita la pregunta", pasa seguido, le ladran un poco, y el usuario intentando arreglar el problema, abre otra pregunta en vez de editar, y después lo de siempre, a los que no les importa el trabajo de un colega (flor de respuesta!!), y se creen poseedores de "la espada justiciera", hacen de las suyas, ahora, cerrar las dos preguntas... ya es pasarse del límite.

Comment: @Yussef la pregunta esta bien cerrada... lo ideal es que sea una pregunta por post ... pero aveces tenemos dos o mas escenarios o comparaciones.... si la pregunta es del mismo usuario, lo ideal es que el usuario coloque los dos escenarios ... sin borrar la primera pregunta ... facilmente tu podias responder las dos en una sola respuesta haciendo las observaciones ... no hay necesidad de un segundo post a menos que la pregunta sea completamente otra, diferente y otro escenario en el cual no se pueda nisiquiera reutilizar el codigo... de lo contrario sigue siendo un duplicado ...

Comment: Son la misma pregunta, el mismo código. En una dice "¿Cómo convierto todo a C#?"; en la otra, "¿Cómo convierto esta parte a C#?".

Comment: @CandidMoe Simplificas el asunto al extremo, y aun así yo leo 2 preguntas distintas en tu texto.- Y si lo llevo al contexto real, más distinto aún, porque "esta parte" no tiene conversión en la primera pregunta, quizás si hubiera pregunta por cualquier otra de las instrucciones podría estar de acuerdo.

Answer (score 2):

La pregunta está bien cerrada... lo ideal es que sea una pregunta por post... pero a veces tenemos dos o más escenarios o comparaciones.... si la pregunta es del mismo usuario, lo ideal es que el usuario coloque los dos escenarios... sin borrar la primera pregunta ...

Fácilmente tú podías responder las dos en una sola respuesta haciendo las observaciones...

No hay necesidad de un segundo post a menos que la pregunta sea completamente otra, diferente y otro escenario en el cual no se pueda ni siquiera reutilizar el código...

De lo contrario sigue siendo un duplicado...

[Duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

> El objetivo fundamental de cerrar preguntas duplicadas es el de ayudar
> a las personas a ***encontrar la respuesta correcta teniendo todas las
> respuestas en un solo lugar.***

---

**Ejemplo Hipotético:**

Si una persona pregunta:

**A. ¿Cómo sé que una variable es un array?** ...

Recibira una respuesta como:

```php
if(is_array($array)){
    //....has lo que te da la gana aquí
}
```

si el mismo usuario pregunta en otro lado:

**B. ¿cómo evaluar true si la variable es un array**

```php
if(is_array($array)){
    return true; //evaluar a true si es array...
}
```

Aunque la pregunta no sean las misma... la misma metodología y lógica de resolución se aplica a ambas... con un mínimo de análisis implementas código de evaluación... entonces la Pregunta B. sera Cerrada como duplicada de la Pregunta A, lo que se espera es que el OP, modifique la Pregunta A de tal forma que quede asi en un solo POST/Pregunta:

> **A. ¿Cómo sé que una variable es un array?** ... 
> --... Update  ...
> **B. ¿Cómo evaluar true si la variable es un array?**  ...

Si después de que hice mi primera y segunda pregunta, ahora quiero saber si un índice existe en el mismo array de mi pregunta anterior yo hago un update de la misma pregunta con esta edición:

> **A. ¿Cómo sé que una variable es un array?** ... 
> --... Update  ...
> **B. ¿Cómo evaluar true si la variable es un array?**  ...
> --... Update  ...
> **C. ¿A partir de los ejemplos anteriores ahora quiero saber cómo evaluar si el índice 'precio' existe en el array?**

De la misma forma debe en una sola respuesta irse agregando las respuestas a cada Escenario:

***Respuesta A:***

```php
if(is_array($array)){
    //....has lo que te da la gana aquí
}
```

***Respuesta B:***

```php
if(is_array($array)){
    return true; //evaluar a true si es array...
}
```

***Respuesta C:***

```php
if(is_array($array) && isset($array['precio'])){
    return true; //evaluar a true si es array si existe el indice...
}
```

Incluso si despues el usuario quiere saber si `$array['precio']` es de tipo `float`

***Respuesta D:***

```php
if(is_array($array) && isset($array['precio']) && is_float($array['precio'])){
    return true; //evaluar a true si el valor del indice es float...
}
```

---

Como te vengo explicando todas las preguntas pertenecen a un mismo **AMBITO** (Escenario, USUARIO) por ende de existir nuevas preguntas o preguntas múltiples pueden ser cerradas como duplicadas por la comunidad aunque no sea 1 sola pregunta, aunque no se resuelvan identicamente o no sea la misma pregunta o solucion.

Entonces esto aplica a array, listas, json, xml, csv, archivos, base de datos, objeto, clases, métodos, funciones y un largo etcétera.

***Lo que se espera es que el usuario edite y agregue que más quiere del mismo espacio de codigo y no agregar mas preguntas al sitio.***

Este concepto es manejado por los (la comunidad) que cerraron la preguntas que mencionas y por este servidor que te responde.

---

***Nota:*** Si la pregunta #1 cerrada por que no demostro el minimo esfuerso, fue editada ***por el OP*** el mismo puede solicitar la re-apertura.

Comment: Una pregunta es duplicada de otra cuando en esencia son lo mismo: `como sumar 2+3` es duplicada de `como sumar 3+4` porque el fondo de ambas es el mismo. Luego el sitio solo permite marcar duplicada una pregunta si es que la anterior tiene una respuesta con al menos 1 voto positivo; la razón de aquello es que la pregunta marcada como duplicada tenga igualmente una respuesta . En este caso la respuesta de (1) no sirve para la pregunta (2) y viceversa.

Comment: Entonces, francamente no tiene sentido lo que me dices. Tu al proponer que se junten ambas preguntas en una sola, y que yo junte las respuestas en una sola, básicamente estás admitiendo que son preguntas distintas, caso contrario no habría necesidad de juntar ni la pregunta ni las respuestas.

Comment: Y menos sentido tiene marcar un duplicado de una pregunta cerrada, si yo pienso que ambas preguntas son iguales, y una de ellas ya está cerrada no marco la otra como duplicada, porque el objetivo está realizado, ya que existe una de ellas cerrada

Comment: El sentido de que sea duplicado no lo decidimos ni tu ni yo, lo decide la *comunidad* y en este caso la comunidad descidio que es un duplicado siguiendo el concepto explicado en mi respuesta y lo que indica el centro de ayuda: _"encontrar la respuesta correcta teniendo todas las respuestas en un solo lugar"_ saludos.

Comment: Tú no sabes bajo qué criterios decidió la comunidad cerrar las preguntas. Tu solo tienes tu opinión y yo la mía. Y en ese marco podemos discutir lo que tú quieras y cuantas veces quieras, que a mí también me gusta hacerlo.

Comment: _"encontrar la respuesta correcta teniendo todas las respuestas en un solo lugar"_ Exacto, si yo buscó como comprobar que el argumento de una función es otra función en C#, el duplicado me lleva a una respuesta que no contesta esa pregunta.

Comment: yo comparto el mismo criterio que la comunidad ...

Comment: @Yussef hay te agregue un ejmeplo hipotetico ... a ver si logras entenderlo ... sin anismo de continuar esta discucion que tengas un excelente dia.

Comment: La norma dice "una pregunta por publicación". Las ediciones son para aclarar la pregunta original, no para crear un "foro de discusión" a la mala.

Comment: @CandidMoe fue el motivo de cierre y como dijo gbianchi ... pudo editar su primera pregunta y hubiera sido digerible ...

Comment: Me refiero a la proposición de ir incorporando respuestas a la pregunta para ir "actualizandola".

Comment: ha eso se hace cuando el tema es sobre refactorizacion ... muy especificamente cuando el usuario tiene mas de un escenario o problema con el mismo codigo... en este caso el usuario avanzo en el codigo ... en lugar de actualizar el post... creo otro y con otra pregunta ... basada en conceptos similares ...

Comment: No se como piensa la comunidad, pero si bien me encuentro de acuerdo con la edición B del ejemplo hipotetico debe de ser una edición, no con la c. La edición C hace un cambio tan drastico que diría que la pregunta pasa a ser otra no relacionada y si pasa a ser otra pregunta. Estoy parcialmente de acuerdo con Candid en ese caso. Si un OP hace eso, estaría convirtiendo la pregunta en una discusión como dice Candid.

Comment: Igual eso de "a partir de los ejemplos anteriores..." no me parecería un buen titulo en una pregunta real. Ese titulo no aporta mucho como tal. Yo diría que tendría que estar dentro del cuerpo eso.

Comment: En tus ejemplos A y B son duplicados, pero ni de cerca se parece a lo que yo planteo. Son preguntas distintas la primera es de tipado de datos y la otra es de una comparación. Y por llegar a un neutro contigo, podría (y no digo que lo esté) estar de acuerdo que en la pregunta 2, podría haber respondido algo como: "la comparación se hace de esta manera, pero no te sirve para lo que tú quieres, para lo que tú quieres debes hacer (y pongo la respuesta de la pregunta1)", Y si está bien responder así, sería el equivalente a decir que la pregunta 1 es duplicada de la 2, no a la inversa como pasó.

Comment: Porque es la (2) la que contendría la respuesta de ambas, no la (1) que no pregunta por la comparación y tampoco se responde haciendo uso de ella

Comment: pues la comunidad esta apoyando este respuesta como valida o por lo meno ya hay 3 por lo minimo de acuerdo con lo que expongo...