# Algunos de los usuarios veteranos tienen problemas de saturación?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Cuanto más observo el "como se manejan", más me voy acercando a tener un perfil de algunos de los usuarios veteranos.
Hoy se cerro, no, se bloqueo, la siguiente pregunta por repetida:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581645/iterar-cambiando-los-elementos-de-una-lista-por-otros-n-veces#
La supuesta duplicación:
[¿Por qué no puedo modificar una lista dentro de un for?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563322/por-qu%c3%a9-no-puedo-modificar-una-lista-dentro-de-un-for)
No hace falta ningún tipo de explicación, no son repetidas... y están muy lejos de serlo.
Corrección, acepto mi error, realmente son duplicadas.

El hecho de que se halla bloqueado, cuando lo normal es cerrarla, muestra claramente el fastidio de la persona que hizo el bloqueo, en el hay encono, hay "deseos de exterminar" al usuario (esto también lo he visto en respuestas que solo pueden ser calificadas de agresivas), esto habla claramente de cansancio, más bien agotamiento.
No puedo juzgarlos, es entendible, años de luchar contra molinos de viento, pueden alterar a cualquiera... tal vez deban tomarse unas vacaciones, no del sitio, sino de las preguntas de los nuevos usuarios, dedicarse a revisar en las colas, solamente a aquellos usuarios con cierto camino andado en el sitio, es mi sugerencia.
Hay otro tipo de problema, aquel usuario de muy alto nivel (hablando de programación), que siente que una pregunta del tipo "como se declara una variable", es una pregunta de bajo nivel para el sitio, cuando en realidad, no lo es, una pregunta de baja calidad es aquella que no está bien formulada según las normas del sitio.
Entre nosotros ha varios tipos, aquellos que tienen alma de profesor,  aquellos que les gusta responder preguntas de muy alto nivel, etc... tenemos que aprender eso de "vivir y dejar vivir", si no quieres contestar una pregunta porque es demasiado simple, no la contestes, deja que otro lo haga, pero no la cierres, no le pongas negativos, simplemente has un paso al costado.

Agrego otra al conteo:
[buennas noches tengo que crear un menú con los 2 métodos que hice el primero en 2 numeros enteros cual es mayor, metodo 2 mayor o menor de edad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581686/buennas-noches-tengo-que-crear-un-men%c3%ba-con-los-2-m%c3%a9todos-que-hice-el-primero-en)
duplicado:
[Manejo de arrays en Java: imprimir en pantalla el nombre de la persona de mayor edad y el de menor edad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580994/manejo-de-arrays-en-java-imprimir-en-pantalla-el-nombre-de-la-persona-de-mayor)
Sin palabras.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta; solo una queja personal que debería ser resuelta en otras instancia.

Comment: Tengo entendido que nadie aquí "juzga una pregunta por su simpleza". Quizá, lo que has notado es el patron de que las preguntas simples las hacen usuarios que también son nuevos en el sitio, más un centro de ayuda que opino que estaría bueno mejorar, y por lo tanto es normal que las preguntas sean de baja calidad. Es más, si a mi no me tienta contestar una pregunta, simplemente no lo hago, como decís.

Comment: No soy profesional, si me equivoco, invito a quien sea que me corrija, pero un usuario me orientó a como hacer mejores preguntas en meta. Yo opino que, para empezar, hiciste dos preguntas en una. Y te recomiendo que, en la primera, no digas "no hace falta explicación", si no que expliques por que tu propuesta de reabrir esa pregunta. En lugar de decir "esto no está bien", hacé una propuesta para que la comunidad cambie su forma de ser y, si nadie está de acuerdo, nada que hacer. Pero al menos habrás hecho tu propuesta y alguien la habrá leido y, quizá, hasta esté de acuerdo.

Comment: Importante: tus preguntas deben sonar como propuestas, no como quejas o imposiciones. No digo que lo sean, pero me ha pasado a mi de hacer propuestas y sonaron como si "impusiera mi opinión por motivos personales".

Comment: Por que la pregunta merece una reapertura? Que argumentos tenés para convencernos? Si la cerraron, es por algo, demuestranos que nos equivocamos. Como habrás notado, el que cerró la pregunta está tan convencido de que es duplicada como vos de que no lo es. Que te da la impresión de que "se juzga a una pregunta por su simpleza"? Mostrar tus argumentos es lo más importante a la hora de proponer o discutir algo.

Comment: La que agregas "al conteo" es claramente una duplicada de la otra. Sin mayor contexto en una pregunta excepto: *"me decia que debia incuir mas detalles jaja por eso el spam"*, y el código de la pregunta, ¿cómo puedes argumentar que **no sea un duplicado**? Por otro lado, cuando hablas de *fastidio* ¿a qué te refieres? Un usuario que se toma el tiempo de leer una pregunta y ubicar un duplicado (cosa que se logra luego de algún tiempo dedicado a moderar el sitio, de forma totalmente voluntaria e incluso altruista), es todo menos un usuario que lo a hecho con *fastidio*.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que algunos usuarios deberian aprender a tomarse un descanso. Los moderadores diamantados lo hacemos de vez en cuando, y hatas tenemos un lindo boton de "estoy de vacaciones" para no ser molestados. Sin embargo, con todo lo otro, no entiendo a que apunta...

Comment: @DanteS, **Tengo entendido que nadie aquí "juzga una pregunta por su simpleza".**, tal vez no te has topado con ella, pero hay declaraciones en las que lo dicen sin ningún tapujo. **no digas "no hace falta explicación", si no que expliques por que tu propuesta de reabrir esa pregunta**, primero nunca propuse reabrir la pregunta, tal vez lo debería hacer, si pongo que no hace falta, es porque considero que es evidente (y acepto que puedo estar equivocado). Mi propuesta es sencilla, zapatero a tus zapatos.

Comment: Tal vez me equivoque en poner ejemplos, no era mi intención exponer a nadie, pero el planteo esta claro.

Comment: Ayer o anteayer, Yussef se tomó el trabajo de contestar un pregunta, para encontrarse con que fue calificada como duplicada, y cerraron la duplicada y la original, yo creo que deberiamos ser más respetuosos con el trabajo de los colegas, recién, en un acceso de fastidio (yo me fastidio más rápido que nadie), intente eliminar mi pregunta... el sistema me dijo

Comment: que no, porque había colegas que habían invertido tiempo y esfuerzo en contestar.... yo voto porque no se cierren preguntas que ya tienen repuesta (correcta), ya que un efecto secundario de esto, es que realmente uno invierte tiempo en elaborar un respuesta para nada, y no dan ganas de contestar más.

Comment: si la pregunta en este caso no demuestra explicitamente por que no es un duplicado de la anterior no se peude re-abrir ... y si un capo como @CandidMoe la Cerro ha de tener sus motivos muy claros.

Comment: Está bien, no propones que se reabra. Y ahora piensas que es duplicada. Eso dejemoslo de lado. Con eso no me meto. Nuevamente, no soy un gurú, pero mi perseptiva (no se si la de alguien mas) es que venís y acusas a algunos usuarios de "no dejar vivir", esto sin mostrarnos, por lo menos, un ejemplo de este comportamiento. Como dije, lo mas importante para hacer una propuesta o "llamar a la reflexión" o discutir algo, es que uses argumentos para demostrar que lo que dices tiene sentido.

Comment: @DanteS., tal vez tengas razón, me cuesta usar el indice (dedo), voy a elaborar una lista de todas las veces que durante la proxima semana, se incurra en alguna de estas conductas y la voy a subir... me voy a ganar el odio de muchos (más), pero en fin, si quiero cambios, hay que agitar el panal.

Comment: Censura los nombres. Que te parece? Yo evito siempre nombrar a usuarios en mis publicaciones.

Comment: @DanteS., si tienes razón, ya empecé la recolección.

Comment: @MarcePuente Antes que todo, agradezco mucho tu apoyo. Pero tu comentario sobre mi caso me parece incorrecto, Jorgesys también me hizo un comentario por chat que apuntaba a "una desesperación por obtener puntos". Ni mi trabajo se pierde al contestar una respuesta, ni menos perjudica en puntaje (siempre que hayan tenido algún voto positivo), al contrario van en mi beneficio ya que nadie más puede responderlas, básicamente compito solo. Que yo pida la reapertura es solo para ayudar al OP y a la comunidad para que existan diversas respuestas al mismo problema

Comment: @Yussef, jamas mencioné el puntaje, tu trabajo si se pierde al cerrar una pregunta, porque ningún otro usuario podrá ver tu respuesta, y por más generosos que seamos de alma, elaborar una buena respuesta y que te la borren "porque si",...

Comment: @MarcePuente El puntaje lo mencionó otro usuario. Las preguntas cerradas permanecen a la vista a menos que eliminen y con posibilidad de recibir puntajes tanto en la pregunta misma como en sus repuestas. Para eliminar una pregunta se realiza otra votación (por usuarios +10.mil) https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools pero ahora con otros criterios, el principal de ellos es que ahora se consideran las respuestas, ya que no se deben perder respuestas de calidad, por lo que en teoría las preguntas que yo señalé  debería solo permanecer solo cerradas.

Comment: @Yussef, idolo, **nadie** busca respuestas en preguntas cerradas, tu excelente trabajo se perdió, solo el OP, (si es que al encontrarse la pregunta cerrada se fijo si tenia respuesta) se beneficiará de tu trabajo, y no es la idea.

Comment: A pesar del proposito del sitio, me da la impresión de que la comunidad no se fija tanto en la utilidad de la pregunta para futuros lectores más allá de que las respuestas mantengan su utilidad en el futuro. Esto lo pienso por que muchas preguntas terminan siendo tan especificas que solo le servirían al OP. Sobre el trabajo perdido, yo nunca he visto preguntas cerradas "por que si" y si una pregunta se considera apta para el cierre, se supone que no tendría que ser respondida (he visto excepciones, pero, por ejemplo, respuestas a ops pidiendo que le resuelvan la tarea, reciben votos negativos)

Comment: @Dante S., te recomiendo que leas esto, y después me digas si no hay preguntas que se cierran porque si... https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5500/problema-con-pregunta-marcada-como-duplicada

Comment: Tiene pinta de que fue cerrada como duplicado "erroneamente", no estoy seguro. Pero siempre hay un motivo. Quizá, como han comentado, alcanzaba con editar la pregunta anterior para mejorarla. Y, en realidad, no fue cerrada por duplicada, si no por ser una publicación que quedaría mejor como edición de la primera. Ten en cuenta que los motivos de cierre o son prefabricados, o dejas un comentario explicando el motivo de cierre. Y duplicada era el motivo más cercano.

Comment: Te publiqué una respuesta analizando la pregunta de meta equivocada xDDD Bueno, ya que la escribí, copiaré la respuesta en la pregunta correcta. Edit: al final, creo que no encaja, así que no lo haré.

Comment: @DanteS., cerraron las dos, la original y la duplicada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Encuentro normal fastidiarse, es que hay preguntas que producen un hastío a cualquiera, no necesitas ser un veterano para ello. Ayer leía una que tenía un problema con "Este botón" y nombraba a "este botón" varias veces, obviamente sin código, pero ni siquiera una foto de "este botón". Es que no es un asunto de novato, es un asunto de mínimo de sentido común. Es como llamar a un doctor por teléfono y decirle "me duele aquí".

En lo personal, me molestan los usuario que comentan "Busca en Google" o los que votan negativo a un novato al minuto de haber publicado, es que no le pueden dar 1h al menos para que aplique correcciones??

Mauricio contreras realizó un comentario:

> ..cuando hablas de fastidio ¿a qué te refieres? Un usuario que se toma
> el tiempo de leer una pregunta y ubicar un duplicado (cosa que se
> logra luego de algún tiempo dedicado a moderar el sitio, de forma
> totalmente voluntaria e incluso altruista), es todo menos un usuario
> que lo a hecho con fastidio

Tú tienes un usuario que se toma su tiempo y revisa. Y decide cerrar una pregunta este usuario está en la categoría que tu describes. Luego llega otro que solo revisa la cola, este otro es un cerrador compulsivo y vota cerrar. Luego llega otro, que es un intermedio de los otros 2, pero ve que ya tiene 2 votos de cerrar lo que le facilita la decisión.

Yo al menos tengo un usuario detectado que es un cerrador compulsivo, cierra demasiadas preguntas y su actividad de publicaciones en el último tiempo es casi nula. Porque puede ser normal que un usuario super activo cierre muchas, pero entrar a solo cerrar preguntas??? Y lo peor, es que si reviso las respuestas generadas, veo que ha contestado preguntas similares en el pasado, es decir ahora que él no se dedica a responder las cierra, hermoso criterio.

Luego hay un par más que cierran menos y publican algo más.

Y hay que tener presente, que las preguntas muy malas son cerradas casi instantáneamente por los usuarios activos. Entonces para las preguntas que están en un área gris tiene un voto casi asegurado con el primer caso que comento, al menos otro de alguno de los otros 2 que son menos compulsivos, lo que se transforma en que de facto solo se necesite un voto.

El mismo ejemplo que pone Marce al final de publicación

[Saber si un numero es mayor o menor y verificar la edad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581686/saber-si-un-numero-es-mayor-o-menor-y-verificar-la-edad)

Duplicada de:

[Manejo de arrays en Java: imprimir en pantalla el nombre de la persona de mayor edad y el de menor edad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580994/manejo-de-arrays-en-java-imprimir-en-pantalla-el-nombre-de-la-persona-de-mayor)

La primera publicación es un ejercicio lvl_1 el tema pasa por `if`, la segunda publicación es lvl_2 es un ejercicio de `arrays`, que aunque el título es similar apuntan a conocimientos distintos

Comment: No podría explicarlo mejor, un ejemplo que es bueno para entender como debería funcionar, este
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581747/por-que-el-resultado-de-los-metodos-da-0-en-mi-operaci%c3%b3n, el OP pregunta, pregunta incompleta, @Mateo, le va indicando los que se necesita, va haciendo preguntas y en tres horas (ahora no puede verse el tiempo trasncurrido), se llega a una pregunta bien formulada, que para más inri, tiene una respuesta aceptada, así debería ser siempre.

Comment: @MarcePuente para mi es buena idea dejar comentarios explicando que se puede mejorar de la pregunta. Pero, más veces que las que me gustaría, el OP ni siquiera se molesta en editar la pregunta, además de que es algo que cuesta trabajo. Igual, como ya he dicho, eso de dejar comentarios explicando, es una cosa que se debatió mucho en todo Stack Exchange. Y la postura que siempre gana es "hacerlo opcional". Yo sinceramente, no le veo mucho sentido a seguir "llamando a la reflexion" o proponer esta idea.

Comment: Pero sin duda, algo que no se hizo mucho es hacer más informativo el centro de ayuda. Y algunos usuarios estamos, por el bien del sitio y de los nuevos, proponiendo que se mejore el centro de ayuda y se de más provecho a las publicaciones en meta.

Comment: Comparto esa ideología. yvotaré a favor del que proponga los cambios.

Comment: Si, estoy de acuerdo con que no se debería dar votos negativos "al minuto". Pero no con los de cierre. No podemos permitir respuestas en preguntas de baja calidad. Hay gente que no da atención a las preguntas y revisa mal. El mejor recurso para evitar esto, ha sido "despertar" al usuario usando auditorías de revisión

Comment: estoy parcialmente de acuerdo ... aunque lo que dices si suele suceder es muy muy muy minimo ... para atribuir tal verasidad a esta publicacion.

Comment: ten en cuenta que los votos de cierre son diarios y limitados ... no hay forma de que un solo usuario cierre mas del 2% de las preguntas por su propia voluntad y si que hay gente con suficiente reputacion para hacerlo... y prefieren dejar esa lavor de moderacion a otros usuarios

Comment: tambien discrepo en el ejemplo... una tarea de nivel 2 puede ser usada como plantilla para una de nivel 1 ... utilizando tus propias palabras la de nivel 2 no resuelve el problema de forma directa ... pero si presenta la solucion adaptable... el problema aqui es el OP peresozo que espera que le hagan la tarea completa sin escribir o entender el codigo...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 El sentido que sean 3 votos y no 1 para cerrar, es que exista un consenso que evite que una sola persona cometa el error de haber cerrado una pregunta que no debía. Es menos probable que 3 personas comentan el error. Si existe una persona que vota compulsivamente, esa probabilidad sube, porque de facto ya son 2 los que están juzgando de buena manera, a esto súmale que existen otro par de usuarios que hace lo mismo pero de forma más esporádica y ya tienes el problema. Y todo esto en preguntas "no tan malas", porque las que son pésimas son cerradas por los usuarios activos

Comment: sigue sin tener relevancia ... si votas para cierre y es rechazado por los otros... se te restringe la herramienta de moderacion ... incluso puedes ver quien te cerro la pregunta y si consideras que esta mal cerrada puedes, pedir que se reabra y reportar a los usuarios ... en todo caso por malas practicas...

Comment: Por ejemplo yo soy de los que más cierre tiene en los últimos 5 meses, porque soy extremadamente activo y cierro esas preguntas "pésimas", pero otros usuarios que no preguntan, no responden, no entran al chat que tengan tantas cerradas es a lo menos anómalo. Son Usuarios que su única participación es cerrar preguntas. Es tanto, que yo los tenía identificado por el solo hecho de revisar la cola, pero saqué la estadística y me da la razón

Comment: pero todo eso depende de si el OP esta comprometido con su pregunta y quiere buscar una respuesta ... pelear por preguntas que los OP no les interesa no tiene sentido

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Con respecto a las preguntas duplicadas, te equivocas. El usuario de la primera pregunta no le sirve la otra respuesta porque tiene un tema que él no conoce, a esa altura el no sabe que existen los array

Comment: por algo los privilegios se dan mediante reputacion ... si una persona consigue el privilegio se supone que tiene el conocimiento minimo para hacer XYZ cosas en el sitio ... y si solo quiere dedicarce a la moderacion y no le interesa dar respuestas o hacer preguntas o perder horas en el chat, es su decicion, no puedes exigir algo distinto ...

Comment: si estas aprendiendo a programar y no sabes que existen los array que se supone que deberias de hacer???

Comment: es como limitar el aprendizaje de una persona solo a lo que tiene en sus narices  ... si un problema puede ser resuelto sin arrays, con arrays, con objetos... lo ideal es presentarle las variantes ... y no solo responder de forma directa ... te doy un ejemplo haca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/581618/315134

Comment: con un solo cambio puede solucionarce el problema, pero hay otras 5 alternativas incluso mas... y no me limite a dar una sola respuesta ... cite todas las formas de poder hacerlo... eso es una buena respuesta ... claro sin salirme de que siga siendo simple...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 No estamos hablando de lo mismo, el proceso de aprendizaje tiene un ritmo y pasos. El usuario preguntó por un problema en específico, mostró código e hizo lo posible por generar una buena pregunta, él nunca menciona arrays en ningún lado, ni su problema tiene relación con ello. A él nunca le respondieron como tú lo hiciste en la pregunta que me linkeaste, a él le cerraron la pregunta porque engañosamente el título es parecido porque mencionan la "edad". Pero son preguntas diferentes

Comment: entonces ese persona no esta en el lugar correcto si quiere aprender mediante un proceso de aprendiza standar debe ir a un curso o tomar tutoriales ... en la comunidad solemos dar lo mejor sobre lo mejor y no a cuenta gotas ... si alguien me pregunta como hago esto ... yo le doy una respuesta basada en MVC y OOP ... que seria el minimo esperado ... haca otro ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/581627/315134

Comment: el op tiene una funcion y yo le ofreci una clase estatica y le adverti sobre controles en el proceso de turnos rotativos ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Discrepamos nuevamente, la respuesta tiene que ser acorde a la pregunta, y como fuese la segunda pregunta no responde la primera

Comment: Y lo otro tú dices que: "si una persona consigue el privilegio se supone que tiene el conocimiento mínimo para hacer XYZ cosas en el sitio" Ahh bueno, pero yo tengo ese privilegio y me sigues discutiendo

Comment: No digo esto con intención de ofender, pero para mantener limpios los comentarios tal vez sea buena idea que sigan hablando por el chat.

Answer (score 7):

Yo cerré la preguntas en cuestión.

Modificar una lista mientras se la recorre es un error fundamental que se manifiesta de diversas formas.

Si una persona entiende eso también entenderá que el caso expuesto por [Iterar cambiando los elementos de una lista por otros n veces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581645/iterar-cambiando-los-elementos-de-una-lista-por-otros-n-veces#) es otra instancia del primero.

Eso está fuera de toda discusión; no existe otra explicación del error y no se requiere más explicación que la dada en [¿Por qué no puedo modificar una lista dentro de un for?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563322/por-qu%c3%a9-no-puedo-modificar-una-lista-dentro-de-un-for).

Antes de acusar que la pregunta está mal cerrada, deberías mostrarnos que **no** es un problema derivado de alterar la lista mientras se recorre.

¿Puedes?

Comment: La primera tiene un error de codificación, que le devuelve un error, la segunda tiene un error conceptual, agrega y quita item a una lista, cuando debería usar dos.+

Comment: No puedo afirmar ni negar que sea duplicada por mi desconocimiento del lenguaje. Pero opino lo siguiente: que el error sea diferente no hace que la pregunta no sea duplicado. Es lo que trata de explicarte Candid Moe.

Comment: Por ejemplo, esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526710/quitar-tildes-al-tomar-un-comando-por-voz es duplicado de esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/518168/convertir-cadenas-con-caracteres-especiales-como-tildes-a-letras-normal. Si bien, ambas tratan escenarios distintos (en la primera se quiere evitar tildes en un comando de voz), el escenario final es el mismo: quitarle tildes a una cadena.

Comment: @DanteS. Explicación: recorre la lista por indice desde 0 hasta N, insertando dos elementos (al final) y eliminando el elemento actual (en medio de la lista). Cuando incrementa el indice, salta sin examinar el elemento siguiente. No es problema Python; pasará lo mismo en cualquier otro lenguaje.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación! Solo un problema, la pregunta que fue marcada duplicada se eliminó.

Comment: @CandidMoe, tienes razón, pido disculpas, pero el fondo de lo que digo, no se supedita al ejemplo que di (voy a editar la pregunta), tiene que ver con la gran cantidad de malas intervenciones que hay en el sitio.

Comment: La pregunta menciona "usuarios veteranos"; tendrás que decir quienes son y que faltan cometieron para poder examinar el caso.