# Cambiemos el sentido de duplicado de "Agregar 0 a la izquierda - PHP"

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos

Hace un rato se marcó la pregunta P1 [¿Cómo completar con ceros el valor de una variable en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73996/83) como duplicada de P2 [Agregar 0 a la izquierda - PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56301/83)

La [revisión de votos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/61862) refleja 4 votos a favor de ello y 2 en contra.

Publico aquí para defender que se invierta el sentido de la duplicación, marcando P2 como duplicada de P1.

Veamos:

- La pregunta P1 es muy directa y fácil, va directamente al grano (no mostró ningún tipo de investigación, pero ese es otro tema).
- La pregunta P1 tiene tres buenas respuestas, todas con puntuación de al menos 5 y por parte de algunos de los más experimentados usuarios de PHP de este sitio ([Muriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74021/83) y [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74997/83)). Para más inri, una de las respuestas [ganó una recompensa de 50 puntos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74997/timeline) por su ejemplaridad.
- La pregunta P2 es larga, con mucho código y etiquetada también con [laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel). La exposición es correcta pero no parece el tipo de contenido rápido de leer para ir directo a la respuesta.
- La pregunta aceptada en P2 es extremadamente breve y sin apenas explicación: es muy parecida a la [respuesta de Muriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74021/83) en P1, pero sin añadir descripciones.

Tal y como están los duplicados, ahora mismo una persona que busque en Google algo parecido y sea dirigida a P1, será automáticamente redirigida a P2 si no tiene una sesión abierta en SOes. Es decir, la dirigiremos a una muestra "pobre" de nuestro sitio, dejándola sin el *placer* de poder ver una muestra "potente".

El argumento que subyace en marcar esta pregunta como duplicada parece ser que P2 es anterior a P1, que se preguntó antes. Lo entiendo, pero no lo comparto. Sí creo que debería haberse marcado como duplicada en un primer momento, antes de tener respuestas; pero la comunidad no lo detectó y ahora reescribir la historia dejando como duplicada la "buena" me parece un error, pues lo que realmente queremos es que las preguntas canónicas sean las buenas.

Tal y como dice Shog9 (uno de los CM de Stack Exchange) en [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/209901) <sub>traducción mía</sub>:

> Si la nueva pregunta es mejor o tiene mejores respuestas, vota para cerrar la vieja como duplicada de la nueva.

Voto pues por reabrir P1 y marcar P2 como duplicada suya.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, este caso es claro. Voy a votar para reabrir la pregunta y cuando esté abierta marcamos la otra como duplicada

Comment: Aunque en otra ocasión dije digo, hoy digo Diego. Con el tiempo he aprendido sobre SOes y su funcionamiento y peculiaridades, así que creo que la duplicada debe ser la peor pregunta, entendiendo pregunta como *pregunta/respuestas*.

Comment: Yo vote para que se cierre como duplicado... más bien por el tiempo... pero no comparto que sea la pregunta p2 como duplicado porque no lo es aunque sea más pobre... es que de ese modo como votaremos aquí en un futuro los duplicados? Por contenido más elaborados?

Comment: @aldanux no entiendo lo de _no comparto que sea la pregunta p2 como duplicado porque no lo es aunque sea más pobre_. ¿Votaste por marcar P1 como duplicada exacta de P2 pero P2 no te parece duplicada de P1? Y sí, creo que es importante que si a la comunidad se le pasa un duplicado y acaba habiendo dos preguntas similares, prevalezca el contenido más elaborado. Tal y como comento en el enunciado, un duplicado quiere decir que las visitas de gente no registrada (es decir, la mayoría de nuestro tráfico) _no pasa_ por esa pregunta y se dirigen directamente a la canónica. Es algo serio, vaya.

Comment: He votado como duplicado la **pregunta** 1 cual es claramente un duplicado de la **pregunta** 2... _las respuestas son más elaboradas_... ¿En que sentido? ¿Quien decide si son mejores o peores? Si el resultado al problema es el mismo! Como dije ya en el comentario...: si comparamos las respuestas hay solo una sola diferencia... la [respuesta de Javi Ps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73996/c%C3%B3mo-completar-con-ceros-el-valor-de-una-variable-en-php/73999#73999) el resto es exactamente igual.... hay millones de respuestas en `SO` con menos de un párrafo y son bien vistas...

Comment: @aldanux por amor a lo razonable: ¿me estás defendiendo que las respuestas a [P2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56301/83) son tan buenas como las de [P1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73996/83)? ¿De verdad una respuesta de una línea y una respuesta bastante específica con MySQL te parece una mejor referencia (o al menos igual) a una duda PHP que tres respuestas diferentes, dos de ellas bastante razonadas? Si es así, me parece preocupante. Por otra parte, creo que estás metiendo demasiadas cosas en el mismo saco. ¿Defiendes que el duplicado sea en el otro sentido? ¿Que no sean duplicadas?

Comment: A ver... quizás sea **yo** que no entienda el termino **duplicado**... veamos la respuesta: P1 (la duplicada): `str_pad($numero, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);` y ahora la P2 (la original): `str_pad($number,6,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); ` ... encuentra me la diferencia y me callo para siempre....

Comment: @aldanux no te sigo ni veo qué estás rebatiendo. Evidentemente son la misma respuesta, pero en P1 hay otras posibles respuestas, también válidas y mejor explicadas. ¿Estamos de acuerdo en ello? Por eso, al ser duplicadas (parece que estamos de acuerdo en esto) lo ideal es marcar como canónica la que tiene mejores respuestas. No es que lo diga yo (que lo pienso) sino que es una práctica consideradad la aceptable por [se]. Me choca tu empeño en mantener una como canónica por el simple hecho de haber aparecido primero.

Comment: Es que me estás diciendo todo el rato que están más elaboradas... yo no lo veo así... la primera repuesta y aceptada es equivalente a la original ósea poca explicación.... la respuesta de muriano tiene más párrafos pero el mismo código y el _hand made_ esta metido en una función... whooohoo... genioso no?... Broma aparte... veo que no vamos a ningún lado ... yo seguiré votando a los duplicados por preguntas ya que en las revisiones uno no ve las respuestas geniales de la comunidad....

Comment: @aldanux eres libre de hacer lo que quieras :) Sí creo que estamos llegando a algún sitio y sería bueno revisitar el debate dentro de unos días, cuando los ánimos se calmen un poco. Me gustaría, si quieres, que replantearas tu férrea convicción de que la pregunta más vieja debe ser siempre la canónica: la clave de la comunidad es construir hacia adelante, luego lo que pasó en el pasado no tiene porqué tener tanto poder.

Comment: Sin problemas... pero me gustaría que la comunidad decida (más)...con **votos** y no **unilateral**... saludos

Comment: @aldanux en eso estamos de acuerdo. Habría sido más pertinente que la comunidad decidiera con sus votos, sin el voto definitivo de un moderador. Supongo que la sensación de unanimidad en Meta y el chat hizo que se precipitara la decisión.

Comment: En relación al debate: [¿Qué tipo de pregunta debería marcarse como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/975/qu%C3%A9-tipo-de-pregunta-deber%C3%ADa-marcarse-como-duplicada)

Comment: @FranciscoRomero ¡gracias! Muy bien traído, pues de hecho veo que allí se contesta con el texto que traduje por aquí.