# Seamos consistentes con las normas del sitio... ¡si es que las hay!

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, duplicados-exactos

Me parece indignante para el OP original, que se haya reabierto [¿Cómo completar con ceros el valor de una variable en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73996/83) y se haya cerrado  [Agregar 0 a la izquierda - PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56301/83) por **duplicado**.

Si vemos [la revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/61862):

> lois6b♦ revisó esto hace 10 horas: Cerrar
>
> Pikoh revisó esto hace 11 horas: Cerrar
>
> fedorqui revisó esto hace 11 horas: Dejar abierta
>
> Patricio Moracho revisó esto hace 19 horas: Cerrar
>
> Shaz revisó esto ayer: Cerrar
>
> Dev. Joel revisó esto ayer: Dejar abierta

Los que han votado para cerrar, incluyendome a mí, son usuarios con bastante experiencia y aportaciones en la comunidad.

Como se ve, el moderador [loisb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) votó también para cerrar y después cuando se publicó [Cambiemos el sentido de duplicado de "Agregar 0 a la izquierda - PHP"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2756/83) en Meta, se ha reabierto el **duplicado** y se cerró el **original**, por nadie más que por el moderador **loisb**. ¿En serio?

El argumento que se dio para hacerlo así como está ahora, es que tenía más voto en las respuestas y *más elaborado*... ummm ¿y qué pasa con los votos a la pregunta? Está claro... quienes contestaron votaron a la pregunta para que sea más accesible... pero de momento está a `-1` (5 a favor 6 en contra).

> ¿¿¿ Ya no es cierto de decir, contra más voto tiene una pregunta es
>   mejor para el `SEO` ???

¡Qué tanto os preocupa!

> ¿¿¿ Y busco ahora preguntas pobres para mejorarlo para ganarme así
>   reputaciones fácil ???

Digo, sería una nueva afición para los que se creen grandes enseñando a los pequeños.

No sé ya que pensar...en verdad... yo ya me quité hace poco por un tiempo como revisor después que hice esta publicación: [¡Por favor, una línea clara ya de una vez como actuar en SO!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475/por-favor-una-linea-clara-ya-de-una-vez-como-actuar-en-so) y al parecer lo haré otra vez (y definitivamente) si no cambian el comportamiento.

**Entonces:**

¿No hay manera que esta comunidad sea consistente con las normas?
Unas veces queremos ser diferente a `SO` y otras veces queremos ser iguales...

¿En qué quedamos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entiendo tu preocupación, y es muy difícil generalizar todos los casos que se dan. Por eso en StackOverflow en Español el sistema se basa en los votos, lo que hace que al menos un determinado numero de personas opinen lo mismo. También tenemos meta para discutir los casos que se encuentren en una zona difusa de las normas.

El caso que nos ocupa se planteó en [Cambiemos el sentido de duplicado de "Agregar 0 a la izquierda - PHP"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2756/15301) por @fedorqui, y actualmente tiene 4 votos positivos y uno negativo. En mi opinión lo que se planteaba ahí tenía lógica, ya que a un usuario que realice en el futuro una pregunta que se considere igual a la planteada sobre el tema le resultará mas útil probablemente la que ha sido posterior ya que las respuestas son mas completas. A ese posible usuario no le importa qué pregunta fue anterior, sino que respuesta puede ayudarle mas.

Hay otra opción que no se tomó en consideración y es marcar una pregunta como duplicada de varias, ya que sólo pueden editar los duplicados los moderadores y los que tienen la medalla de oro del tag.

En cuanto a que a veces queremos ser igual que StackOverflow y otras no, yo te puedo dar mi opinión. Aquí se ha dicho en múltiples ocasiones que no tenemos que seguir las normas del sitio en inglés, que somos autónomos y podemos decir lo que queremos que sea el sitio. Yo trato siempre de fijarme en lo que se decide en StackOverflow por una sencilla razón: la experiencia. Allí por tiempo y por número de usuarios han vivido todo tipo de situaciones. Pero yo que soy usuario de ambos sitios también veo cosas que me gustaría cambiar aqui si tengo la posibilidad.

Algo en lo que si puedo estar de acuerdo es que tal vez @lois6b se precipitó realizando ese cambio de forma unilateral, y debía haber esperado a que la pregunta hubiera sido reabierta por votos.

Por último te animo a que sigas realizando tareas de revisión. Todas las opiniones son útiles y necesitamos la ayuda de todos los usuarios con reputación suficiente para moderar.

Answer (score 6):

Las normas no son exactas. Si lo fueran, las colas de revision serian un mero paseo y no habría disputas ni discusiones por chat/meta.

La pregunta más reciente tuvo que haberse cerrado como duplicado cuanto antes... pero no fue así y generó respuestas.

Voté para cerrar, porque la temporalidad indica que la última es la duplicada de la anteriormente publicada.

Sin embargo, en el chat y en [una pregunta en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2756/cambiemos-el-sentido-de-duplicado-de-agregar-0-a-la-izquierda-php), se habló sobre estas dos publicaciones y es cierto que las respuestas de la que actualmente está abierta son mejores que la publicada con anterioridad.

¿Qué se puede hacer aquí? Porque la otra pregunta es más antigua ... ¿vamos a dejar *perderse* respuestas mejores?

Mirando preguntas de meta.se como [¿Cómo proceder con preguntas duplicadas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/368819)(en inglés) dice:

> Usually a recent question will be closed as a duplicate of an older question, but this isn't an absolute rule. The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate.
>
> Normalmente la pregunta más reciente es la cerrada como duplicada de la antigua pero no es una regla fija. La regla general es mantener la pregunta con las mejores respuestas y cerrar la otra como duplicada. <sub>(editad si mi traducción no es la más apropiada)</sub>

Y para mi es lo importante. La calidad del sitio, de las preguntas y de las respuestas.

Una posibilidad que no se trató, en la pregunta anterior de meta respecto a estas dos publicaciones, es la combinación de ambas preguntas en una. Por consecuente, una de las preguntas es borrada pero todas las respuestas estarán en una sola publicación.

Comment: No me acaba de convencer la opciónd de combinar ambas preguntas en una. Esto haría que las respuestas de una se movieran a la otra, cosa que quedaría algo rara en ambos casos. Lo que sí podríamos hacer es mejorar el enunciado de la pregunta canónica para que luzca más.

Comment: **¿Entonces es valido copiar preguntas y mejorarlas?** ¿La comunidad cuando vota no tiene validez? ¿Hay que avisar a todos los usuarios cuando hagan un pregunta que puede ser cerrada en un futuro por duplicado? ... sigo sin entender tu acción unilateral y el termino **duplicado**... si comparamos las respuestas hay solo una sola diferencia... la [respuesta de Javi Ps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/73999/6491) el resto es exactamente igual solo que esta metido en una función _hand made_ y el otro no...

Comment: @aldanux como dije, la pregunta reciente tuvo que haberse cerrado como duplicado. La falta de busqueda por parte del que preguntó y de los que contestaron conllevó este duplicado. Imagino que estarás de acuerdo en la calidad de las respuestas de la ultima. que harias?  hacer que las respuestas vayan a la original y cerrar la ultima publicacion ?

Comment: Yo entiendo perfectamente cual es el problema... pero que criterios tiene que tener entonces uno en un futuro? Porque eso va a pasar mas a menudo... mas usuarios... mas preguntas duplicadas...mejores respuestas..  .se responde más rápido... ¡problemón! ¿ Y que haría yo ? Ya nada... el pescado ya esta vendido....

Comment: Yo creo que los que responden no deberian lanzarse a contestar inmediatamente, si no buscar la existencia de dicha pregunta en el sitio. Asi se solucionaria estas situaciones. Si encuentran un duplicado, marcarlo y responder en la original (y mejorar la pregunta si se puede)

Comment: Pues si... pero eso (creo) que ya es otro tema