# ¿Qué criterios fueron tenidos en cuenta para marcar una pregunta sobre mysql como duplicada?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, duplicados-exactos

La semana pasada me encontré con la pregunta [Consulta MySQL, de Filas a Columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309320/consulta-mysql-de-filas-a-columnas) bastante interesante y me animé a plantear una respuesta, sinceramente trabajé unas horas para terminar de responderla. Ahora me encuentro que fue marcada como duplicada de [¿Cómo puedo crear una tabla pivote con una columna que combine dos columnas ya existentes?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267642/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-crear-una-tabla-pivote-con-una-columna-que-combine-dos-columnas-ya-e).

Revisé la [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267642/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-crear-una-tabla-pivote-con-una-columna-que-combine-dos-columnas-ya-e) que "ya tiene una respuesta" y para mí esa respuesta, aunque fue aceptada por el OP, no resuelve del todo el problema planteado.

Para mí no son duplicados: se resuelven aplicando la misma técnica pero son casos diferentes.

Por favor, ilumínenme.

PD: Ojalá que no marquen esta pregunta como duplicada ;).

Comment: Pues podría ocurrir que esta se marcara como duplicada porque ya se ha tratado el tema antes. Por ejemplo: [¿Qué tipo de pregunta debería marcarse como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/975/7176). Tambien relacionado: [¿Qué hacer cuando una pregunta está marcada cómo duplicada y es mejor que la original?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1035/7176)

Comment: Que cosas, replanteo la pregunta entonces?

Answer (score 2):

Tu respuesta no puedo votarla porque no conozco el tema con suficiente profundidad. Lo que sí lamento es haber votado como duplicado sin tener conocimiento extenso sobre este tema concreto de MySQL. De hecho, como vi que la otra tenía un título demasiado genérico, [lo cambié](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/267642/revisions).

Dicho lo cual, veo distintas cosas:

- Puede que la pregunta no sea de lo mismo exactamente.
- En cualquier caso, la pregunta es muy pobre y cuesta saber exactamente qué quiere el autor, que tampoco ha mostrado mayor interés por ella (ni comentó, ni editó, ni aceptó... [nada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/149354/edu?tab=activity)). Por ello, probablemente hubiera sido bueno esperar a tener más datos por parte del usuario.
- Así como está la pregunta, difícilmente permitirá que alguien pueda *aprovechar* el conocimiento que derrochas en tu respuesta: los usuarios no registrados van a ser redirigidos automáticamente a la *canónica*, por lo que no verán tu respuesta. Y eso es una pena.
- Dicho lo cual, y dado que pusiste gran empeño: ¿crees que la pregunta podría ser salvable?

  - Si sí, edítala, mejórala, indica la diferencia con la duplicada propuesta.
  - Si no, coge tu respuesta y llévala a una pregunta preparada por ti mismo y que encaje con una situación más amplia. De este modo podrás tener toda la *libertad* de explayarte después en la respuesta en los aspectos más interesantes.

Resumiendo: sugiero o editar salvajemente la pregunta actual, o bien publicar otra *ad hoc* y en ella añadir tu respuesta.

Comment: Siento si mi acción fue equivocada, pero apoyo y apoyaré si el amigo incluso pública una pregunta/respuesta que quede como solución general a una pregunta del tipo, asumí que cerrarla era lo adecuado pero incluso de ser necesario seré el primero no solo en reconocer mi error sino además votar para reabrirla

Comment: Faltaría más hombre, nada que lamentar! Siempre es difícil determinar duplicados, pues el AP puede tener unas coordenadas en mente, los lectores otras y los que responden otras.

Answer (score 1):

Aclarando algunos puntos:

- Me pareció un duplicado, pues intentaba obtener un resultado similar al de la pregunta que marque
- A quien respondió de hecho le he votado positivo, por el gran esfuerzo y contenido en su aporte
- Quién pregunto no daba mucho contexto de su duda, pero de ser necesario y mejora su pregunta votaré para re abrirla
- Si tal vez quién pregunto hubiera dado más pistas entonces tal vez a mi me hubiera quedado claro que buscaba algo similar pero con un método ligeramente distinto

Dicho lo anterior.

**Invito a quien respondió como ya se lo externe a @fedorqui publique una pregunta/respuesta que tal vez hasta pueda quedar como wiki de comunidad y sirva de referencia general ante la duda expuesta**